# How can I create a Nested For Loop to enter data in my Nightmare javascript code

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, nightmare

I have two JSON files. I want to compare the JSON objects in both files; ***json1 and json2***. If there is an object in the array in the first json file ***(json1)*** file that is not present in second json file ***(json2)***, I would like to pass it through the below Nightmare js code then push it the object to the second json file using **.push()**.

---

**JS CODE:**

```js
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({
  show: true
});
var json1 = require('./json1.json')
var json2 = require('./json2.json')

for (var i = 0; i < json1.length; i++) {
  for (var c = 0; c < json2.length; c++) {
    if (json1[i] !== (json2[c])) {
      console.log(json1[i])
      return nightmare
        .goto(json1[0].searchOn)
        .insert('.gLFyf', json1[0].searchText)
        .wait(3000)
        .end()
        .evaluate((json2, json1) => {
          return json2[c].push(json1[i])
        }, json2, json1)
        .then()
    } else {
      console.log('End!')
    }
  }
}
```

**JSON1 Data**

```js
[
    {
        "searchOn": "https://www.google.com",
        "searchText": "I love google"
    },
    {
        "searchOn": "https://www.google.com",
        "searchText": "I'm hungry, where can I eat?'"
    }
]
```

**JSON2 Data**

```js
[
    {
        "searchOn": "https://www.google.com",
        "searchText": "What's the date?"
    },
    {
        "searchOn": "https://www.google.com",
        "searchText": "What is the internet"
    },
    {
        "searchOn": "https://www.google.com",
        "searchText": "What's the weather like today?"
    }
]
```

However, the Js code gives me this error: **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**.

The code also does not execute the nightmare js code on all objects on the loop (only performs the task for the first item alone.

Please advice on how I can fix these errors.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can't iterate through an object by indexes. This would work with arrays, which are a type of object with keys mapped to indexes starting at 0. If you want to iterate through any object use Object.keys or for-in operator. You can find out how to do both [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-a-plain-javascript-object-with-the-objects-as-members).

The same is true about push, which is an [array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Answer (score 0):

The interaction between multiple code errors can be difficult to predict and/or explain. Here's a few to review:

1. `if (json1[i] !== (json2[c]))`

The entries in `json1` and `json2` are objects created by `JSON.parse`. They are *always* different objects. Comparing equality of their primitive property values will be needed to see if the objects contain the same data.

2. `return nightmare` ...

This would synchronously return the pending promise returned by `then()` at the end of the promise chain from the function in which this code is executing, so only the first loop iteration is performed. The `return` keyword needs to be removed for the loop to complete.

3. `json2[c].push(json1[i]` in one of the call backs

has two problems:

a) it is executed asynchronously. If the `return` is removed and the loop completes, `c` and `i` are equal to the length of `json2` and `json` respectively and return undefined if used as array indices. This is an asynchronous programming issue - refer to [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/5217142) for solutions.

b) `json2[c]` is a plain object, not an array, so it doesn't have a `push` method. You probably meant to push a value on the end of `json2`, not onto an entry in it.

4. There is no `catch` clause on the nightmare promise chain. Uncaught promise rejection errors may become fatal in the future.

Note I have no exact reason why `json2[c]` is undefined in the code snippet - are you quoting from actual code rather than the cut down example posted? I would also suggest looking into asynchronous functions and the `await` operator as a means of looping asynchronous operations.