# get data from json file using javascript and show data out table

Tags: javascript, json

I tried to get the data from the json file with javascript but it doesn't output the data
here is my code:

```js
fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/trvodi/test/main/json1.json')
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
var json = data;
var i;
    var iLength = json.data.item.length;
    for (i = 0; i < iLength; i++) {
        alert(json.data.item[i].FromMember);
    }

}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

please help me. thank you

Comment: You're doing .length on an object.

Comment: The json.data.item is not an array. you need to run a for loop like https://jsfiddle.net/Lf7honqy/

Answer (score 1):

If you'd add the following line:

```js
console.log(json.data.item, json.data.item.length);
```

You'll see that `json.data.item.length` is `undefined` because `json.data.item` is an object.

I'd recommend using

```js
for (let i in json.data.item) {
    let item = json.data.item[i];
    console.log(item.FromMember);
}
```

To loop over the objects as shown in this demo:

```js
fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/trvodi/test/main/json1.json')
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
      for (let i in data.data.item) {
          let item = data.data.item[i];
          console.log(item.FromMember);
      }
  })
.catch((err) => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

---

For more info about why (and alternatives) I'd choose `for (let i in json.data.item)`, please see the following question/answer:

[How to loop through a plain JavaScript object with the objects as members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-a-plain-javascript-object-with-the-objects-as-members)