# JSON parse map is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

when i make data map i get error.
where is the problem?

**Error : UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: betsModel.map is not a function**

axios response ( String !):

```
var betsModel = {"13721":{"IdG":"1","N":"[] - 1","T":7,"A":true},"13722":{"IdG":"1","N":"[] - 2","T":7,"A":true},"6352":{"IdG":"1","N":"Zaman Sona Erdiğinde Beraberlik","T":1,"A":true}};
```

Parser

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {
    var uri = 'x';
    Axios({
        method: "GET",
        url: uri,
        timeout: 5000
    }).then(async response => {
        var e = response.data.match(/\= \{(.*?)\}\}\;/g);
        var betsModel = e[1].replace(/= /g,'');
        betsModel = JSON.parse(betsModel.replace(/}};/g,'}}'));
        betsModel.map(a => {
            console.log(a);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is an array method. `betsModel` is an object. There is no `Object.prototype.map`. Unrelated: don't use `map` without return value. Use `forEach` instead.

Comment: @jabaa forEach is also an array method. It will not work for an object.

Comment: @DonRajithaDissanayake Yes, I know. That's the reason I wrote _"Unrelated"_ in front of it. But you should not use `map` to call a function for each element without return value.

Answer (score 0):

Object iteration and array iterations are two different things. Here "betsModel" is an object. Hence map function will not work.

There are few ways to achieve what you do.

**1. Object.values** [MDN Reference for Object.Values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```
Object.values(betsModel).map(value => {
         console.log(a);
    });
```

**2. For In** [MDN Reference for , FOR IN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```
for (const prop in betsModel) {   
        if (betsModel.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
             console.log(`obj.${prop} = ${obj[prop]}`);   
        } 
     }
```

Here is a similar question
[How to loop through a plain JavaScript object with the objects as members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-a-plain-javascript-object-with-the-objects-as-members)

Comment: Why would you create an array of `undefined` in your first snippet? `forEach` is much faster in that case.