# Foreach when key is not a number

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

In my project i push a array into a table in firebase realtime database. Firebase generate a token and not a numeric id for each array:

```html
{
    "-N2mToYDj-i8ToErmaUj": {
        "anzahl": 2,
        "groesse": 0.5,
        "name": "getraenk1",
        "preis": 5.5
    },
    "-N2mX3RPnDXxWMHMJScy": {
        "anzahl": 1,
        "groesse": "0.25",
        "name": "getraenk2",
        "preis": 2.2
    },
    "-N2mXBT8c7EKlIgyrU72": {
        "anzahl": 1,
        "groesse": "0.5",
        "name": "getraenk3",
        "preis": 3.4
    },
    "-N2mXZD1BoCslj81Lcya": {
        "anzahl": 1,
        "groesse": "1",
        "name": "getraenk4",
        "preis": 5.2
    "-N2m_g8GutpAFqsN4WsP": {
        "anzahl": 1,
        "groesse": "0.33",
        "name": "getraenk5",
        "preis": 3.2
    },
}
```

How can i work with each object when the key value is not numeric. ForEach() does not work for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-a-plain-javascript-object-with-the-objects-as-members

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just care about the values, wrap the result in [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values). If you care about the keys also, wrap the result in [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) instead.

```js
const data = {"-N2mToYDj-i8ToErmaUj":{"anzahl":2,"groesse":0.5,"name":"getraenk1","preis":5.5},"-N2mX3RPnDXxWMHMJScy":{"anzahl":1,"groesse":"0.25","name":"getraenk2","preis":2.2},"-N2mXBT8c7EKlIgyrU72":{"anzahl":1,"groesse":"0.5","name":"getraenk3","preis":3.4},"-N2mXZD1BoCslj81Lcya":{"anzahl":1,"groesse":"1","name":"getraenk4","preis":5.2},"-N2m_g8GutpAFqsN4WsP":{"anzahl":1,"groesse":"0.33","name":"getraenk5","preis":3.2}};

Object.values(data).forEach(value => console.log("value", value));

console.log("===================");
Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => console.log("key", key, "value", value));
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're getting back an object not a list which is why forEach isn't working. You would need to loop through the keys of the returned object and pull the corresponding record that way.

You can do something like this to loop through the keys:

```
var object = {"one":"data-1","two":"data-2"}
var keys = Object.keys(object)
keys.forEach(function(key){
    console.log(key); 
    console.log(object[key])
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your data stored in `test` object.
you can use `Object` function in javascript to work with any object. For accessing all key you can try this:

```
Object.keys(test).map(key => { // key in here can be for example -N2mToYDj-i8ToErmaUj
    const data = test[key] // this is the full object that each key points to
/* 
   {
        "anzahl": 2,
        "groesse": 0.5,
        "name": "getraenk1",
        "preis": 5.5
    }
*/
})
```

Comment: don't use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) unless you're making a new array with the `forEach`, otherwise just use `forEach`