# Extracting values from complex JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to JavaScript and am looking for a way to: first, extract values from a desired key in a complex JSON object. Second, if the value does not equal a given string, print the parent key. Here is a simplified JSON object that needs to be parsed. There are many more entries in the file.

```
{
    "Test1": {
        "protocolName": "Test1",
        "createdAsProtocolName": "AnalyticsTest1",
        "message": "Protocol already exists!",
        "importStatus": "success",
        "protocolApplicationName": "Flexi-Protocol",
        "protocolId": 1,
        "applicationId": 5
    },
    "Test2": {
        "protocolName": "Test2",
        "createdAsProtocolName": "AnalyticsTest2",
        "message": "Protocol already exists!",
        "importStatus": "success",
        "protocolApplicationName": "Flexi-Protocol",
        "protocolId": 2,
        "applicationId": 5
    },
    "Test3": {
        "protocolName": "Test3",
        "createdAsProtocolName": "AnalyticsTest3",
        "message": "Error",
        "importStatus": "failed",
        "protocolApplicationName": "Flexi-Protocol",
        "protocolId": 3,
        "applicationId": 5
    },
    "Test4": {
        "protocolName": "Test4",
        "createdAsProtocolName": "AnalyticsTest4",
        "message": "Error",
        "importStatus": "failed",
        "protocolApplicationName": "Flexi-Protocol",
        "protocolId": 4,
        "applicationId": 5
    }
}
```

I want to check each test's ['importstatus'] for "success" and if any say otherwise, save them in an array ["Test3", "Test4"]

Comment: What have you already researched and/or tried?

Comment: To be clear, is this coming to you as a string (JSON)? Or as an Object?

Comment: That makes no sense. [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) is a string.

Comment: @PM77-1 I can loop through and grab every keys value or I can access each value directly by hardcoding obj["Test1"]["importStatus"] but that obviously won't work when I have a couple hundred entries

Comment: Does this help? [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop through a plain JavaScript object with the objects as members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-a-plain-javascript-object-with-the-objects-as-members)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each key/value pair in yourObject, filter out any with importStatus of success, and return the keys of the rest.

```js
const arrayOfFailures = Object.entries(yourObject)
  .filter(([k, v]) => v.importStatus !== "success")
  .map(([k, v]) => k);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was trying to figure out.