# Return the Maximum Depth of objects in a Nested Collection (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, recursion, collections, nested, max

I looking for a suitable algorithm that will return the maximum depth of a collection of objects within a hierarchy of collections. I have a root object which may or may not contain a collection of objects of the same type, of variable number. Each of these child objects, themselves may contain a collection of the same type and variable number, and so-on, down to any depth. (see diagram).

[image: Object hierarchy]

I looking for the best algorithm that would return an integer that represents the level of the deepest collection in the hierarchy. (So in my diagram that would be 4.).

I've tried the following function recursively but it is always out by one.

```
 var getLevelFunc = function (children) {
             var depth = 0
            for (var c = 0; c < children.length; c++) {
                let child= children[c];
                if (child.children() != null && child.children().length > 0) {
                    var tempDepth = getLevelFunc(child.children());
                    if (tempDepth > depth) {
                        depth = tempDepth
                    }
                }
            }
            return 1 + depth;
        }
```

Many thanks

Comment: If it's always out by one, can you just add or remove one from the total? What are you passing into getLevelFunc in the first instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of the data structure you've got so I mocked a simpler one with out any `children()` methods, hope it still makes sense though.

I think that part of what makes your solution a bit trickier is that you start with the children rather than the node, afterall if you have one node with no children it should still have a depth of one (if I've understood things correctly). By passing the depth into the `getLevelFunc` at each stage I think it probably makes it easier to see what should be going on in the code.

```js
const tree = {
  name: 'root',
  children: [
    {
      name: 'Child 1',
      children: [
        { name: 'Child 1.1' },
        {
          name: 'Child 1.2',
          children: [
            { name: 'Child 1.2.1' },
            { name: 'Child 1.2.2' },
            { name: 'Child 1.2.3' },
          ]
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'Child 2',
      children: [
        { name: 'Child 2.1' },
        { name: 'Child 2.2' },
      ],
    },
    { name: 'Child 3' },
  ]
};

const getLevelFunc = function (node, start_depth = 1) {
  let depth = start_depth;
  
  for (const child of (node.children ?? []))
    depth = Math.max(depth, getLevelFunc(child, start_depth + 1));
  
  return depth;
};

console.log(getLevelFunc(tree));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with the [@ut8pia/classifier](https://github.com/ut8pia/classifier) library, you'd recognize this as a common scenario addressed by the "search and selection" pattern. Viewing the calculation of a tree's maximal depth in this light reveals its essential equivalence to computing all descendants from the root node. Therefore, it's more conceptually sound to mirror this equivalence in your code. Rather than creating a specific function, I highly recommend tackling the problem by employing a unified pattern.

```
import { ArrayQueue } from "@ut8pia/classifier/queue/ArrayQueue.js";
import {Path} from "@ut8pia/fluent/util/Path.js";
import assert from "assert";

   const root = {
        name: 'root',
        children: [
            {name: 'Child 1',
            children: [
                { name: 'Child 1.1', children: [] },
                { name: 'Child 1.2', children: [
                    { name: 'Child 1.2.1', children: [] },
                    { name: 'Child 1.2.2', children: [] },
                    { name: 'Child 1.2.3', children: [] }
                ]}
            ]},
            {name: 'Child 2', children: [
                { name: 'Child 2.1', children: [] },
                { name: 'Child 2.2', children: [] },
            ]},
            { name: 'Child 3', children: [] }
        ]},

        n = 11,

        depth = 4;
```

This pattern utilizes a `Queue` as a stack to explore a search `space`. This `space` is a function that provides adjacent points corresponding to each explored point.

For instance, when exploring all descendants of the root node, the point represents the node itself, and the search `space` is defined by the function `node => node.children`.

```
const
    search = new ArrayQueue()
        .let(root)
            .search(node => node.children)
```

To compute the maximal depth, the point refers to a `Path` of nodes, and the `space` is defined by the function that extends the path across all children of the last node: `path => path.across(path.last.children)`.

```
const
    search = new ArrayQueue()
        .let(Path.of(root))
            .search(path => path.across(path.last.children)),
    got = search
        .toArray()
            .map(path => path.length)
                .reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b), 0)
```

The `search` instance belongs to an iterable class that provides methods to narrow down the `search`, combine it with additional iterations, or modify it. For example, the `toArray()` method converts the search into an array.

You can validate the proposed solution by:

```
assert.equal(search.toArray().length, n);
assert.equal(got, depth)
```