# function that will go through and filter the object, then return a filtered object

Tags: javascript

Given an object and a filter function, write a function that will go through and filter the object, then return a filtered object.

```
Function:
deepFilter(obj, filter)

Input Object: 
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: {
    c: 2,
    d: -3,
    e: {
      f: {
        g: -4,
      },
    },
    h: {
      i: 5,
      j: 6,
    },
  }
}

Callback Function:
const filter = (n) => n >= 0

Output:
{ a: 1, b: { c: 2, h: { i: 5, j: 6 } } }
```

My implementation:

```
function deepFilter(obj, filter, resultObj){
    if(typeof(obj)!=="object"){
        return obj
    }
  for(let key in obj){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        const filteredValue = deepFilter(obj[key], filter, resultObj)
        if(filter(filteredValue)){
            resultObj[key] = filteredValue;
        }
    }
  }
   return resultObj
}
```

The output isn't what is expected.

```
My output:
{ a: 1, c: 2, i: 5, j: 6 }
```

Is there a different approach to this problem or is it something that I'm missing in the function implementation?

Comment: `Is there a different approach to this problem` sure, one that produces the expected output is a good start

Comment: Seems to give an error: https://jsfiddle.net/c9qa7o86/  and your implementation doesn't use `filter`

Comment: Hello, can you please give an example of the output that can be expected

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that you are reusing your `resultObj`, so nested objects are getting flattened.

I'm also unsure why you're using `hasOwnProperty` there. I feel like you're building in a lot of unnecessary checks. All you need is something like this, where you go through each key recursively and add it to the result only if it maches the filter:

```js
function deepFilter(obj, filter) {
  let result = {};
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      let subObj = deepFilter(obj[key], filter);
      if (Object.keys(subObj).length) {
        result[key] = subObj;
      }
    } else if (filter(obj[key])) {
      result[key] = obj[key];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

// Input Object: 
const obj = { a: 1, b: { c: 2, d: -3, e: { f: { g: -4, } }, h: { i: 5, j: 6 } } }

// Callback Function:
const filter = (n) => n >= 0

// Output:
// { a: 1, b: { c: 2, h: { i: 5, j: 6 } } }

console.log(deepFilter(obj, filter));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could treat every nested object as own object and return only an object if the nested value/objects have wanted values.

```js
const
    deepFilter = (object, condition) => {
        let result;
        
        for (const key in object) {
            const value = object[key];
            if (value && typeof value === "object") {
                const nested = deepFilter(value, condition);
                if (nested) (result ??= {})[key] = nested;
                continue;
            }
            if (condition(value)) (result ??= {})[key] = value;
        }
        
        return result;
    },
    object = { a: 1, b: { c: 2, d: -3, e: { f: { g: -4 } }, h: { i: 5, j: 6 } } },
    isPositive = n => n >= 0,
    result = deepFilter(object, isPositive);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you forget to collect the child objects containing filtered data. Check whether the child objects have data after filtering and them to the parent object.

I've added `K: 0` to the source object to have some falsy value to test with.

Some fancy and fast no-braces solution:

```js
const walk = (obj, flt, out = null, add = null) => Object.keys(obj).forEach(
    (k, _, __, v = obj[k]) => typeof v === 'number' ? flt(v) ? (out ??= {})[k] = v : 0 : (add = walk(v, flt)) && ((out ??= {})[k] = add)
  ) || out;
console.log(walk(object, n => n>=0 ));
```

```html
<script>
const object = { a: 1, b: { c: 2, d: -3, e: { f: { g: -4 } }, h: { i: 5, j: 6 } }, k: 0};
</script>
```

More readable:

```js
const walk = (obj, flt) => {
  let out = null;
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    const val = obj[key];
    if(typeof val === 'number'){
      if(flt(val)) (out ??= {})[key] = val;
    }else{
      const add = walk(obj[key], flt);
      if(add !== null) (out ??= {})[key] = add;
    }
  });
  return out;
}

console.log(walk(object, n => n>=0 ));
```

```html
<script>
const object = { a: 1, b: { c: 2, d: -3, e: { f: { g: -4 } }, h: { i: 5, j: 6 } }, k: 0};
</script>
```

```
` Chrome/120
---------------------------------------------------------
Alexander     1.00x  |  x1000000  162  166  168  172  175
Nina Scholz   2.87x  |  x1000000  465  467  475  476  484
---------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const object = { a: 1, b: { c: 2, d: -3, e: { f: { g: -4 } }, h: { i: 5, j: 6 } }, k: 0 };

// @benchmark Nina Scholz

const deepFilter = (object, filter) => {
        const entries = [];
        
        for (const key in object) {
            const value = object[key];
            if (value && typeof value === "object") {
                const sub = deepFilter(value, filter);
                if (sub) entries.push([key, sub]);
                continue;
            }
            if (filter(value)) entries.push([key, object[key]]);
        }
        
        return entries.length
            ? Object.fromEntries(entries)
            : undefined;
    };
    
    deepFilter(object, n => n>=0);
    
// @benchmark Alexander

const walk = (obj, flt, out = null, add = null) => Object.keys(obj).forEach(
(k, _, __, v = obj[k]) => typeof v === 'number' ? flt(v) ? (out ??= {})[k] = v : 0 : (add = walk(v, flt)) && ((out ??= {})[k] = add)
  ) || out;

walk(object, n => n>=0 );


/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function flattenObject(obj) {
  const result = {};

  function recurse(curr, prop) {
    if (Object(curr) !== curr) {
      if (curr >= 0) {
        result[prop] = curr;
      }
    } else if (Array.isArray(curr)) {
      for (let i = 0, l = curr.length; i < l; i++) {
        recurse(curr[i], prop + "[" + i + "]");
      }
      if (l == 0) {
        result[prop] = [];
      }
    } else {
      let isEmpty = true;
      for (let p in curr) {
        isEmpty = false;
        recurse(curr[p], prop ? prop + "." + p : p);
      }
      if (isEmpty && prop) {
        result[prop] = {};
      }
    }
  }

  recurse(obj, "");
  return result;
}

const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: {
    c: 2,
    d: -3,
    e: {
      f: {
        g: -4,
      },
    },
    h: {
      i: 5,
      j: 6,
    },
  },
};

const flattenedObj = flattenObject(obj);

// Filter the keys and remove negative values, using the last property name
const output = {};
for (const key in flattenedObj) {
  if (flattenedObj[key] >= 0) {
    const lastPropertyName = key.split('.').pop();
    output[lastPropertyName] = flattenedObj[key];
  }
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this is a classic interview question which can be easily solved using **recursion**.

So basically you need to remove all negative numbers from the object ***key-value*** pairs.
You need to write a RECURSIVE
function that will take care of any level of nesting.
Here is an example:

```js
const filterNegativeValuesFromObject = (inputObj, parentKey) => {
  let result = {};
  for (let key in inputObj) {
    const currentValue = inputObj[key];
    // if current value is an object, recursively call the function again to handle nesting and we also pass the current key as parent key, so that values can be stored in the current key to prevent flattening of the object
    if (typeof currentValue === "object") {
      const tempResult = filterNegativeValuesFromObject(inputObj[key], key);
      result = { ...result,
        ...tempResult
      };
    }
    // if current value is NOT an object, there are two cases
    else {
      // if there is a parent key
      if (parentKey !== "") {
        // current value of key is negative, remove it
        if (currentValue < 0) delete key;
        else {
          let temp = {};
          temp[key] = currentValue;
          result[parentKey] = { ...result[parentKey],
            ...temp
          };
        }
      }
      // if there is NO parent key
      else {
        // current value of key is negative, remove it
        if (currentValue < 0) delete key;
        else result[key] = currentValue;
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
};


console.log(filterNegativeValuesFromObject(inputObj, ""))
```

```html
<script>
  const inputObj = {
    a: 1,
    b: {
      c: 2,
      d: -3,
      e: {
        f: {
          g: -4,
        },
      },
      h: {
        i: 5,
        j: 6,
      },
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: @mplungjan Nope, wrote it myself from scratch. That is why it's verbose, I like to write code that is easily understandable by other people.

Comment: Ok, I was actually not looking at the code, just the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I've made slight adjustments to your code, and now it functions as expected.

```
const 
    data =     { a: 1, b: { c: 2, d: -3, e: { f: { g: -4 }}, h: { i: 5, j: 6 } } },

    expected = { a: 1, b: { c: 2, h: { i: 5, j: 6 } } },

    filter = obj => Number.isInteger(obj)? obj >= 0
        : typeof(obj) === 'object'? Object.keys(obj).length
            : true,

    deepClone = (obj, filter) => {
    
        if(typeof(obj) !== "object") {
            return obj
        } else {
                    
            const got = {};
            
            for(let key in obj) {  
              
                const next = deepClone(obj[key], filter);
                if(filter(next)) {
                    got[key] = next
                }                
            }

            return got
        }
    }
        
assert.deepEqual(deepClone(data, filter), expected)
```

However, it's worth noting that it occurs only if neither functions nor arrays are nested within your data. A more comprehensive solution would require a slightly more complex code implementation. Is it advisable to create a specialized, intricate function for a specific purpose like this?

While conceptually, cloning the tree structure of an object is akin to calculating its maximal [depth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77651685/23020032) or iterating through its [properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77664122/23020032), if you address each of these tasks separately with dedicated functions, you won't be able to reuse any part of the solution to tackle the others.

Here's an alternative approach based on the "search and selection" pattern as outlined in the [@ut8pia/classifier](https://github.com/ut8pia/classifier) library. You might find it helpful to read the previous examples linked above that illustrate the application of such a pattern before continuing with this example.

```
import {ArrayQueue} from "@ut8pia/classifier/queue/ArrayQueue.js";
import {Path} from "@ut8pia/fluent/util/Path.js";
import assert from "assert";
```

The `data` object is conceptualized as a tree of properties where each property is defined by a pair `[key, value]`. The function  `children(value)` returns all the children entries of an entry from its `value` (the key is irrelevant, so it's not passed as an argument).

```
function children(value) {
    return !(value instanceof Object)? []
        : typeof(value) === 'function'? []
            : Array.isArray(value)? obj.map((item, i) => [i, item])
                : Object.entries(value)
}
```

From this standpoint, our calculation aligns seamlessly with our prior applications of the pattern. This similarity is distinctly mirrored in the code.

```
const  
    space = path => path.across(children(path.last[1])),
    search = new ArrayQueue()
        .let(Path.of([undefined, data]))
            .search(space);
search
    .which(filter)
        .then(build)
            .each()
```

The `search` iterates through all property paths within the `data` object, providing methods to either filter using `which(filter)` or rebuild using `then(build)` only the paths that we intend to clone into the `expected` object. The final call `each()` is necessary to rebuild the tree by actually executing the iteration. The `search` itself is a formal definition of an iteration and its methods (but `each()`) produce formal definitions from formal definitions (please, refer to the library's online documentation).

The `filter` and `build` functions are defined below:

```
const 
    got = {},
    map = new Map([[data, got]]),

    filter = path => {
        const [key, value] = path.last;
            return typeof(value) === 'object'? false
                : Number.isInteger(value)? value >= 0
                    : true
     };            

function build(path, map) {

    let 
        key = path.last[0],
        src = path.last[1],
        trg = map.get(src);

    if(!trg) {
        const parent = build(path.prev);
        trg = !(src instanceof Object)? src
            : typeof(src) === 'function'? src
                : Array.isArray(src)? []
                    : {};
        parent[key] = trg;
        map.set(src, trg)
     }

     return trg                
}
```

It's crucial to highlight that although the proposed solution may seem intricate due to involving several auxiliary functions such as `children(value)`, `filter(path)`, and `build(path)`, only the simplest among them: `filter(path)` is specific to the problem at hand. The remaining two functions are not tied to the specifics of our calculation; they could be universally defined and reused indefinitely.

You can validate the proposed solution by:

```
assert.deepEqual(got, expected)
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
for (const key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    const value = obj[key];
    if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
      const filteredValue = deepFilter(value, filter);
      if (Object.keys(filteredValue).length > 0) {
        result[key] = filteredValue;
      }
    } else if (filter(value)) {
      result[key] = value;
    }
  }
}
return result;
};
```

Comment: Please edit and update your answer to a [mcve] and add some description

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).