# How to learn CouchDB API without documentation?

Tags: javascript, couchdb

Since CouchDB has very few API documentation (at least I can not find it), I would like to inspect some JavaScript objecs myself. What is the best way to do this?

For example, show functions recive the request object `req` as argument. How to find out, which properties (cookies, requested url,...) this request object precisely has?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your specific question - how to write `_show` functions - see the relevant documentation in the [CouchDB Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/): [Formatting with Show and List](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Formatting_with_Show_and_List).  That document then cross-references to the [External Processes](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/ExternalProcesses) documentation for details on the request object.  In general, the wiki is a treasure trove of information - most of the API documentation is there.  It can just take some looking.

You can also experiment directly with JavaScript, as indicated by Nathan.  You could write a show function that just stringifies the parameters (with `JSON.stringify()`) and displays them so you can see what they actually are.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [CouchOne Docs](http://docs.couchone.com/couchdb-api/index.html) and the open [CouchDB Book](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/index.html).

Comment: Both have no information about the request object passed to a show function :-(

Comment: Just write JSON.stringify(req) in your response for testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can write code to inspect what properties an object has, see [Iterating over every property of an object in javascript using Prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587881/how-to-iterate-over-every-property-of-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not happy with the couchdb documentation either.

In the CouchDB Guide there is some information about the req object that is passed to the list function: http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/transforming.html

I guess it will look quite the same in show functions.

But you should also be able to use toJSON(req) in order to get its content.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question, I often find myself writing a quick show/list function something like this example to quickly jog my memory about request (or other) options:

```
function (doc, req) {
    provides("text", function () {
        return JSON.stringify(req, null, 4);
    });
}
```