# Deduplicating using nodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, node.js, csv

My goal is to take in a CSV file which contains approximately 4 million records and process each record while scrubbing the data of a particular field. The scrubbing process we have actually creates a reversible hash but is a time consuming process (almost 1 second). What I would like to do since there are only about 50,000 unique values for that field is to set them as properties of an object. Here is a pseudo example of how the object will be built. You can see that for duplicates I plan to just overwrite the existing value (this is to avoid having to loop through some if based search statement.

```
    var csv = require('csv');
    var http = require('http');
    var CBNObj = new Object;
    csv()
    .fromPath(__dirname+'/report.csv',{
        columns: true
    })

    .transform(function(data){
        CBNObj[data['Field Value']] = data['Field Value'];
    });
    console.log(CBNObj);
```

This should create my object something like this.

```
myObj['fieldValue1'] = 'fieldValue1'
myObj['fieldValue2'] = 'fieldValue2'
myObj['fieldValue3'] = 'fieldValue3'
myObj['fieldValue1'] = 'fieldValue1'
myObj['fieldValue1'] = 'fieldValue1'
```

I have looked over some good posts on here about iterating over every property in an object (like this one [Iterating over every property of an object in javascript using Prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587881/how-to-iterate-over-every-property-of-an-object-in-javascript-using-prototype)) but I am still not exactly sure how to acccomplish what I am doing. How can I then take my object with 50k properties and essentially dump the values into an array so that I can end up with something like this?

```
myArray = ['fieldVaue1','fieldVaue2','fieldVaue3']
```

EDIT: I could also use some assistance on the first part here because I am getting a null value or undefined when I try and set the object properties. I also still need help then traversing through the object properties to build my array. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is important to note that the order of an object's keys is **[not guaranteed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Parameters)**.  You could very well end up with `['fieldValue3', 'fieldValue1', 'fieldValue2']`, so you'll have to do extra work if order is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var csv = require('csv');
var AcctObj = new Object();
csv()
.fromPath(__dirname+'/report.csv',{
    columns: true
})
.on('data',function(data){
    AcctObj[data['Some Field Value']] = data['Some Field Value'];
})
.on('end', function(){
    for(var prop in AcctObj) {
        if(AcctObj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
        //Do something here....
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You know that the keys of your object are the unique values you want. You just need an array. In node.js you can use Object.keys().

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

It's a standard way to take all the keys of an object (that aren't provided by the prototype chain) and put them into an array. So your example looks like this.

```
var csv = require('csv');
var AcctObj = new Object();
var uniqueArray;

csv()
.fromPath(__dirname+'/report.csv',{
    columns: true
})
.on('data',function(data){
    AcctObj[data['Some Field Value']] = data['Some Field Value'];
})
.on('end', function(){
    uniqueArray = Object.keys(AcctObj);
});
```

Object.keys also does the hasOwnProperty check internally, so it's similar to the answer by @DvideBy0. It's just one step to the array you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didnt know about .keys. I will definitely have some use for this in the future :)