# Getting the value of an object's property where the key is a blank string

Tags: javascript, properties, javascript-objects

Given this object:

```
: http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom
gd: http://schemas.google.com/g/2005 
openSearch: http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/ 
app: http://www.w3.org/2007/app; 
media: http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/
```

How do I get the value of the first property? I suspect this is an easy process, but I'm drawing a blank. Thanks in advance.

The object is built as such:

Server side (php):

```
$namespaces = $feedXML->getNamespaces(true);
$arr = array(
'Status' => 'Success',
'Message' => 'Feed fetched.',
'Namespaces' => $namespaces,
'Feed XML' => $feedXML
);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Client side (JS):

```
   var output = '';
    for (property in dataj["Namespaces"]) {
        output += property + ': ' + dataj["Namespaces"][property] + '; ';
    }
    alert(output);
```

I would like to be able to check the namespaces to see if this is Atom or RDF.

It sounds like just iterating each property is going to be the best way.

Comment: Does that code actually work? Because all I get is [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token `:`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4kNhP/).

Comment: What's the exact code ? How is built your object ?

Comment: This is not valid JavaScript object. And I am sure the api sends the properly encoded JSON object (e.g. `{"xmlns": "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", "xmlns$gd": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005"}`).

Comment: @SalmanA I have no idea what api you are talking about

Comment: Can you post (relevant part of) the JSON generated by your PHP script?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're trying to get the value of the property whose key is an empty string, then you can do

```
var value = myObject[''];
```

If you try to get the "first property" of an object, you can't because properties in javascript objects aren't ordered.

Comment: This is a JSON object of the namespaces XML namespaces. Are you saying I should decode this object back to an array? Would that even work with a blank key?

Comment: This is correct, however you could iterate over the object's properties to get at the value.

Comment: Did not know you could reference an empty string key that way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Properties aren't guaranteed to be ordered. You can however iterate over all properties to find the right one (if you know what you are looking for):

```
for(var prop in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
        doSomethingWith(obj[prop]);
}
```

Reference: [Iterating over every property of an object in javascript using Prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587881/iterating-over-every-property-of-an-object-in-javascript-using-prototype)

Then get the key by

```
var value = obj[key];
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty This doesn't look like it would would on what appears to be a blank property.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
var test_bject = {'test': 1, 'test2': 2, 'test3': 3}, first_value;

for (i in test) {
  first_value = test_object[i];
  break;
}
```

Comment: That would work. I should have better worded what I was trying to do.