# Clear all script-set variables easily (Javascript/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, dom, variables, reset

I'm trying to find a simple way to reset all current variables in the DOM. My app has a 'locked' state, but currently, when locked, the last set of information is still visible in the DOM if you look using Firebug for example.

I know all the names of all variables, but I don't want to have a really cumbersome script including all of them (there are approx. 300) where I explicitly clear their values.

Does anybody know if there's a way to 'purge' the DOM of all set vars?

Apologies in advance if this is a silly question, and thanks for any responses. My app uses jQuery extensively, but all my Javascript/jQuery searches have come up blank.

Comment: why would you wan't to do that? And what do you mean by "locked" state?

Comment: are you attaching variables to DOM elements as properties?  DOM doesn't have variables, per se and answerers seem to be confused about what you need to clear.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're attaching variables to DOM elements as properties (which you should be careful not to create a cyclic reference and trigger IE memory leaks; see: [crockford article](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/memory/leak.html)).

In the article about leaks, Mr. Crockford gives a function for purging function references from all DOM elements, which is similar to what you need:

```
function purge(d) {
    var a = d.attributes, i, l, n;
    if (a) {
        l = a.length;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
            n = a[i].name;
            if (typeof d[n] === 'function') {
                d[n] = null;
            }
        }
    }
    a = d.childNodes;
    if (a) {
        l = a.length;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
            purge(d.childNodes[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Where he has

```
if (typeof d[n] === 'function') {
```

Replace with logic that checks for your custom attributes/properties (keep a list handy in an array if you use a lot of different ones, and make sure that none of your property names conflict with standard attributes like src, title, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cluttering the DOM with global variables, try putting a scope around them (using functions).

Better explained here: http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/

Answer (score 0):

Every global scope variable or function is actually defined within current window. You can enumerate members of an object ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)). If you can separate user defined variables, then you have everything you need. May be you can define an empty window and compare those variables. See the following

```
var a=5

alert(window.a); //OR
alert(window["a"]);
```