# for/in statement

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble understanding the for/in statement in JavaScript.

The [book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101992) which I'm using explains it as:

```
for(variable in object){
    statement
}
```

So take for example:

```
var links = {
    link1: {img: '/img/link1.jpg', w: 100 },
    link2: {img: '/img/link2.jpg', w: 140 }
};
```

How would I print out all the links?

If I use:

```
for(x in links){
    document.write(x);
}
```

It writes out the 2 property names `(link1, link2)`, but I'm having trouble understanding how to access those properties nested a level deeper, my first thought was a nested `for/in` loop but I just don't understand the syntax. E.g. In the code above, does `x` refer to the property name? If so wouldn't `x.img` get the `img` property? Or is my thinking way off?

I would appreciate any references or links to examples, I just find the 2 code examples from the book don't help me understand as much as I'd like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x` refers to the property name, but not the property value. So to access the property value, you'd need to do `object[x]`.

So, for example:

```
for (key in links) {
    var linkProperties = links[key];

    document.write(key + ": \n");

    for (property in linkProperties) {
        var propertyValue = linkProperties[property];
        document.write("    " + property + " = " + propertyValue + "\n");
    }
}
```

would give

```
link1:
    img = /img/link1.jpg
    w = 100
link2:
    img = /img/link2.jpg
    w = 140
```

Also worth mentioning: as discussed in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/85992/3191), a `hasOwnProperty` guard clause is almost always desired when using `for ... in`.

Answer (score -1):

```
for(x in links){
    document.write(links[x]);
}
```

Comment: This is unsafe, as it will return any property assigned to the `Array` prototype as well.