# Stop javascript prototyping from killing for loops

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

A few people I work with include on their sites some javascript I wrote and host. But some of those sites use prototype.js or some other framework and its causing some big problems.

For example:

```
var test = {"one":[{"a":"b"}]};
for (var i in test.one) { console.log(i); }
```

The expected result of this would be "0" in the console (i being the key to that array)

But if I go to a site like prototypejs.org and run the same code in firebug's console, I get a list of all the prototype junk (each, eachSlice, etc..)

Try running it in your console here on stackoverflow, it returns "0" as expected.

How do I prevent this? Any good workarounds?

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object

Comment: You have to use `for(i=0; i < test.one.length; i++)`, `in` is unsafe because of this.

Comment: Sorry about dupe, I swear I searched extensively first :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either test that each property you enumerate is *NOT* in the prototype

```
for (var i in test.one) { 
   if (test.one.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      console.log(i); 
   }
}
```

or don't enumerate arrays.

```
for (var i = 0, ii = test.one.length; i < ii; i++) {
     console.log(i);
}
```

Any code that extends `Object.prototype` is not your problem. You should not have to guard against that.

Comment: Thanks! I think I have to use hasOwnProperty() instead of for(i...i++) because i'm dealing with string keys (aka object properties, aka associative array keys) where there's no such property 'length'.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn to work nicely with others, by not using a for in loop without checking for hasOwnProperty on each iteration, or you can explode all their code at the start of yours:

```
for(var p in Array.prototype)delete Array.prototype[p];
```

It will only destroy non-native properties.

Do the same for Object and anything else you want neutered.

Comment: +1 for cleaning up the prototype! Teaches them right for corrupting native prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

Prototype.js stuffs `Array.prototype` with additional methods.

Here's an excerpt from `prototype.js`:

```
  Object.extend(arrayProto, {
    _each:     _each,
    clear:     clear,
    first:     first,
    last:      last,
    compact:   compact,
    flatten:   flatten,
    without:   without,
    reverse:   reverse,
    uniq:      uniq,
    intersect: intersect,
    clone:     clone,
    toArray:   clone,
    size:      size,
    inspect:   inspect
  });
```

You can find all these properties in the output of your first `for..in` loop.

Can be prevented by not iterating over arrays with `for..in` and instead using `var i; for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)`