# Navigator Object in javascript. How to determine all properties

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enumerate the properties of a javascript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)

Good day!

I want to determine all the properties of my navigator using javascript by doing this following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    for(var property in navigator){ 
        str="navigator."+ property;   //HAVING A PROBLEM HERE...
        document.write(property+ "&nbsp;&nbsp;<em>"+ 
        str+"</em><br />");
    } 
</script>
```

But the concatenation of my str variable prints as it is. What i need is the actual value of the property.

eg. navigator.appCodeName should print mozilla instead of navigator.appCodeName itself.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to use `navigator[property]` to access the values assigned to the properties.

```
for(var property in navigator){ 
    var str = navigator[property]
    document.write(property+ "&nbsp;&nbsp;<em>"+str+"</em><br />");
}
```

You could also benefit from dropping `document.write()`, it's rarely the best way to modify the DOM.