# Is it possible to loop through an object, and get the key names ($key => $value)?

Tags: javascript, loops, object-literal, for-in-loop

In PHP, we can loop through an associative array, and get the values of *both the key and the value* like this:

```
$myArray = array(
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2'
);

foreach($myArray as $key => $val){
    echo 'The value of "'.$key.'" is "'.$val.'".\n';
}

/* Output:
The value of "key1" is "value1".
The value of "key2" is "value2".
*/
```

Is there any way this can be done in javascript?

```
myObject = { 
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2'
};

for (val in myObject) {
    // check hasOwnProperty and what not...

    // Now, how do I get the key value?
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question has a concept reversed: JavaScript's for/in loop gets you the key, not the value. You then obtain the value by using the key.

```
var myObject = { 
        'key1': 'value1',
        'key2': 'value2'
    },
    key,
    val;

for( key in myObject )
{
    if( Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call( myObject, key ) )
    {
       val =  myObject[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply `myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)`?

Comment: Crockford mentions a few reasons, but the main one is just in case you have overridden `hasOwnProperty()` for your object.

Answer (score 2):

That's easy, using `myObject[val]`