# what's the key sequence when enumerating an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I already know [how to enumerate an object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object). My question is what's the key sequence while enumerating.Is it by A-Z or time ordered?

code

```
var a = { 
          "a":""
         ,"b":""
         ,"c":""};
for (var k in a) {
    console.log(k);
}
```

output

```
a,b,c
```

code

```
var a = { 
          "b":""
         ,"a":""
         ,"c":""};
for (var k in a) {
    console.log(k);
}
```

output

```
b,a,c
```

code

```
var a = { 
          "b":""
         ,"a":""
         ,"c":""};
a.d = "";
for (var k in a) {
    console.log(k);
}
```

output

```
b,a,c,d
```

Comment: You can find more info about it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-in-a-for-in-loop/280861#280861

Comment: @Narendra thanks, it's exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually the order is the time it was added, but the specification for the `for in` loop [says](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-12.6.4):

> The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties (step 6.a in the first algorithm, step 7.a in the second) is not specified.

So you cannot really rely on one specific order.