# Javascript Multidimensional Array: Add Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array, addition

So I have a multidimensional array like:

```
myArr = [["venue",2],["venue",16],["inning",2],["inning",4],["inning",32],["hithard", 4]]
```

I would like to add the similar values up. So in the end I just have:

```
"venue" = 18, "inning" = 38, and "hithard" = 4.
```

Can you give me an example of how to accomplish this? Either with Javascript and/or jQuery

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want an array or object? Object is `{ venue=18, inning=36, hithard=4}` and Array is `[["venue", 18], ["inning", 38], ["hithard", 4]]`

Comment: Well I'm going to be turning this into a querystring to pass to a service so I'm sure either will work well

Comment: you need a hash (object)

Comment: @Corey [check my post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10488083/297641) and demo >> http://jsfiddle.net/skram/bVxPq/4/ <<

Comment: @Vega, this works very well...I like it. Thank you!

Comment: I'm going to add this to my list of interview questions, it's brought out a ton of interesting approaches

Comment: @Corey you can always use [$.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to parse the obj to a query string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you want an array or object. If object, stop it is 1st pass and `tmp` in below code should return you the object as `Object { venue=18, inning=38, hithard=4}`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/bVxPq/4/)

```
var tmp = {}, keys;
for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    keys = myArr[i][0];
    tmp[keys] = (tmp.hasOwnProperty(keys))? 
              (tmp[keys] + myArr[i][1]):myArr[i][1];
} //tmp - will return you a Object { venue=18, inning=38, hithard=4}

var output = [];
for (keys in tmp) {
    output.push([keys, tmp[keys]]);
} //output will return you an array as [["venue", 18],["inning", 38],["hithard", 4]]
```

Comment: this doesn't have query string output, mine below does

Comment: @Gavriel OP mentions that he will be using it in query string. However initial post doesn't say anything about query string. Let say if he want this in AJAX data, then he can just use it right away..

Answer (score 3):

```
myArr = [["venue",2],["venue",16],["inning",2],["inning",4],["inning",32],["hithard", 4]];
values = {};
for (i=0;i<myArr.length;i++){
   if ("undefined" == typeof values[myArr[i][0]]) {values[myArr[i][0]] = 0;}
   values[myArr[i][0]] += myArr[i][1];
}
arr = [];
query_string = "";
for (i in values) {
    // if you want it in an array:
    arr.push('"' + i + '" = ' + values[i]);
    query_string += (query_string.length ? "&" : "") + i + "=" + values[i];
}
​console.log(arr);​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Ta97E/2/

you can use values to create the query string

Comment: what's wrong with it? This is dynamic and it sums them by category

Comment: I see what you are going for here Gavriel. This solution goes toward the idea of not limiting your code to a static requirement. What if a fourth or fifth statistic was needed? by creating the object based on the key and then incrementing into that key value pair, this solves the problem. I would have approached it only slightly different. This does not deserve a down vote.

Comment: @MikeRobinson Where in the question does he specify that the answer has to be an array result? That is a terrible assumption. The question effectively asks, "how do I add these three things up".

Comment: @ChristopherSmithson You have a point, I was just going with the idea of maintaining datatypes just in case there's part of the code further on that rely on this configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Check this code:

```
var final = {};
for (var i in myArr) {
    var item = myArr[i];
    final[item[0]] = (final[item[0]] || 0) + item[1];
}

console.log(final);​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/UVJEb/

Comment: strictly speaking it misses `if (myArr.hasOwnProperty(i))`, otherwise it would be a perfect general solution

Comment: @OttoAllmendinger You mean `final.hasOwnProperty`? I think `(final[item[0]] || 0)` covers it absolutely. Can't imagine the situation when it won't work.

Comment: the `hasOwnProperty` check filters inherited properties: http://stackoverflow.com/a/86306/92493

Answer (score 2):

[Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) solution:

```
 sums = _.reduce(myArr, function (obj, item) { 
    obj[item[0]] = (obj[item[0]] || 0) + item[1]; 
    return obj; 
 }, {});

 // sums = {"venue":18,"inning":38,"hithard":4}
```

A little dirtier in jQuery

```
sums = {}

$.each(myArr, function (i, value) {
    sums[value[0]] = (sums[value[0]] || 0) + value[1];
});
```

Edit: add jQuery version

Comment: I like your dirty jQuery solution also. Thank you!