# What is the correct way to use an Array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to javascript. So this question might not be good.

```
var arrQue = new Array(10);
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arrQue[i] = new Array(6);
  }
```

This code works perfectly but I wanted to know without giving the array size, how can I make something like this (the following code doesn't work):

```
var arrQue = new Array();//don't know the size
  for (var i = 0; i < arrQue.length; i++) {
    arrQue[i] = new Array();//don't know the size
  }
```

And also the code contains two times creating new array. Is there easier or best way to do that creating multiple array?

And later I've to access like this:

```
arrQue[0][6] = "test";
arrQue[23][3] = "some test";
```

---

I found this method but think wrong somehow?

```
Object.size = function(obj) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
};

var arrQue = [];
var size = Object.size(arrQue);
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   arrQue[i] = [];
   var nextSize = Object.size(arrQue[i]);
}
```

Comment: What is the result you want?

Comment: Check the link i have added along with my answer..

Comment: Provide me with an example input, then i can help you out.

Answer (score 4):

```
var arrQue = [];

for (var i = 0; i < length of your inputs; i++) {
    arrQue.push(input);
}
```

Take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp)

Check out the **Array Object Methods** there.. that's all the stuff you need.

You can have arrays,arrays of objects... etc..depending upon your requirement.

Comment: `[]` is technically "better" than `new Array()`.

Comment: You're saying the length of your inputs, but I don't know the size exactly.

Comment: Allright fair enough,how are you inputting? 
Is it through a click...? or JSON? or... how?

Comment: What you want is "Dynamically adding values into multidimensional array".
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487970/javascript-multidimensional-array-add-values

Comment: You have kinda deviated away from the initial question,i suggest you create a new question with proper inputs and what you want as the output. I will be happy to answer it ,if i can.

Comment: And for the click,you have to pass the value of the inputs from the input field to the function where the values are being pushed into the array.All this being handled by an onClick event handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrQue = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arrQue.push(input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**you might be looking for the push method:**

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(your value);
```