# get root json element in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

This is my json ... 
using javascript .. i want to output just the name  of the root  in this case services
then traverse through the individual elements in the array

```
{
    services: {
        46: {
            servicetypeid: "27",
            serviceid: "51",
            servicename: "Parking",
            description: "Parking Related Payments",
            optioncode: [],
            inputid: [],
            price: [],
            categoryidentifier: []
        },
        47: {
            servicetypeid: "27",
            serviceid: "52",
            servicename: "Markets",
            description: "Markets Related Payments",
            optioncode: [],
            inputid: [],
            price: [],
            categoryidentifier: []
        },
        48: {
            servicetypeid: "27",
            serviceid: "53",
            servicename: "PSV",
            description: "Public Service Vehicles",
            optioncode: [],
            inputid: [],
            price: [],
            categoryidentifier: []
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `services` is not an array but an object.. you should use an array instead

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enumerate the properties of a javascript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not JSON format data, you can loop thru the object:
To get the root key, you could do:

```
var rootKey;
for(var prop in tst) {
 console.log( prop ); //will give "services"
 rootKey = prop;
}
```

And to loop thru all the items:

```
for( var key in tst[rootKey] ) {
  for( var key1 in tst[rootKey][key] ) {
    console.log( "key:" + key1 + " --- Value:"+ tst[rootKey][key][key1] );
 }
}
```