# How can I traverse this Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enumerate the properties of a javascript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)

```
{ 
       347655082: {
                    album:{
                            title: "A",
                            genre: "Pop",
                          }
        },

        347655083: {

                    album:{
                            title: "B",
                            genre: "Rock", 
                          }
        }
}
```

Normally the "outside" key is the same, so I can easily target the nested objects.
In the case the "outside" key is variable which can be anything.

```
albums = JSON.parse(json); //parse json storing it in albums
```

I cannot run a foreach on albums, say "albums has not method foreach".

```
albums.forEach(function(album, i){


}
```

Comment: strictly, what you have there is a Javascript _object literal_, which looks somewhat like JSON, but has a looser syntax.  This is what you get _after_ you've called `JSON.parse()` on real JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use `.forEach()` on arrays.  Your `albums` entity is an `Object` so you should use `for ... in ...)`

```
for (var key in albums) {
    if (albums.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // do something with albums[key]
        ...
    }
}
```

For code targetting node.js or any other ES5 implementation you could probably omit the `if` clause - it's only needed if you've got code that has unsafely added stuff to `Object.prototype`.

Answer (score 1):

ES5 has a great method for iteration object own enumerable properties - [Object.keys(obj)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).
I prefer the following iteration method:

```
Object.keys(albums).forEach(function (key) {
   console.log(albums[key]);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

That's not valid json
The valid json would be:-

```
    {
    "347655082": {
        "album": {
            "genre": "Pop", 
            "title": "A"
        }
    }, 
    "347655083": {
        "album": {
            "genre": "Rock", 
            "title": "B"
        }
    }
}
```

keys in json need to be double quoted as shown.

To validate json checkout jsonlint.com

Comment: Yes, i forget the opening/closing brackets (corrected) but that does not answer my question.

Comment: @saeed: No, it's not only the closing bracket. Keys must be enclosed in quotes to be valid JSON. If what you posted is actually your `albums` object and you have no problems parsing the original JSON, then say so. Then there is no reason to mention JSON at all, it's just confusing.

Comment: @FelixKling it's a common mistake - the OP has merely confused an object literal with JSON, and then picked the wrong question title...

Comment: @Alnitak: I know and you are probably right, but if we don't point this out explicitly, it will never get better ;)

Comment: I stand corrected. I should not have used term json. Its a javascript object literal.