# Iterate thru Hashtable while checking each key, value pair Javascript

Tags: javascript, hash, foreach

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enumerate the properties of a javascript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)

I"m trying to iterate thru a hashtable. But I need to check the values each time I run through it.

How would I use a foreach table to do this?  in sudo code I'd like to do this:

```
var tHash = {
 name: n,
 date: d,
 labels: l,
}

foreach(value in tHash){
   if(tHash.name== somevalue){do something};
   if(tHash.label == somevalue) {do something};
```

That's essentially what I'd like to do but not real sure how to start it out.

Edit:  The isn't just one hash it's an array of hashes...I should've mentioned that at the beginning the way I put the code is the way I was loading the array of hashes with a for loop.

Comment: If you know what you want each property to be, you shouldn't need a loop. Just check the value of each property.

Comment: well I basically have a huge list of names date label pairs.  I'm putting them into Google spreadsheet and so I need to check the name first(so I don't duplicate) and then the label second(since there are  4 different label types and I only want to add to the sum of the label that is in the current key/value pair).

Comment: you can check the property "name" within a for...in loop.

Answer (score 30):

You can iterate through the Keys of a Hashobject with a `for ... in` Loop. 
You get each property (key) of the Hash and can also access the Value with the property.

```
var tHash = {
  name: "n",
  date: "d",
  labels: "l" 
}

for (var key in tHash){
  console.log(key + " -> " + tHash[key]));   
  // if (key == "name") doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

This works, as is.

```
var tHash = {
 name: "Jeremy",
 date: "0",
 labels: 4
}

if (tHash.name === "Jeremy") {alert("Welcome, Master")};
if (tHash.labels !== 0) {alert("There is a label waiting")};
```

Comment: Does not answer on how to iterate