# What am I doing wrong here with knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to dynamically create observables but its not quite working. Here is what I have:

//this type works

```
   this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
   this.Age = ko.observable(data.Age);
```

//This is what I want to work

```
   for (var propertyName in data) {
         this.propertyName = ko.observable(propertyName);
     }
```

This produces just the property name i.e "Name", and "Age" but the first one produces the value and name when I debug like "Name" is "John".

Comment: What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object

Comment: I want the second one to behave like the first one that works.

Comment: @Martin That's not the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about:

```
for (var propertyName in data) {
    this[propertyName] = ko.observable(data[propertyName]);
}
```

*this.propertyName* will actually set a property named "propertyName". By using brackets, you can use variables to define a property.

*ko.observable(propertyName);* was defining an observable with the property name as its value.

You might also want to check if the value is an array so you can create an observable array where needed:

```
for (var propertyName in data) {
    var value = data[propertyName];
    if ($.isArray(value)) { // assuming your using jQuery
        this[propertyName] = ko.observableArray(value);
    } else {
        this[propertyName] = ko.observable(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I tried that similar, did not know to take of the "." from 'this'