# How do I return a property name?

Tags: javascript

Im not quite sure how to do this, or what to google to find the answer...

```
for (var c in cfd){
   if (cfd[c] <= cfd[c+1]) {
       nextfunk = ???
   }
}
```

After the for-loop thing I want nextfunk to have the value of the name of the lowest valued cfd.

Thanks.

Comment: Check this out:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object

Comment: Not enough information.  What is this cfd array?  What does it contain?  How and where is the "name" of the cfd stored?  Maybe `nextFunk = c;`?

Comment: @Henrik: Does none of the answers work for you?

Comment: No, they did. I just got so captivated when I went back to coding.
Although still @PSR's answer generates an error, and it sure would be nice to be able to use such clean code.
Thanks for all your answers. This forum is truly amazing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (var c in cfd){
   if (cfd[c] <= cfd[c+1]) {
       nextfunk = c;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
for (var c in cfd){
   if (cfd[c] <= cfd[c+1]) {
       nextfunk = c;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var value = Math.max.apply(Math, cfd);
```

Comment: When I try this it says "Cannot read property 'max' of undefined". Can the fact that cfd is an object, and not an array have something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

It would be `c` as it contains the Name:

```
nextfunk = c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked to return it:

```
var nextfunk;

for (var c in cfd){
   if (cfd[c] <= cfd[c+1]) {
       nextfunk = c;
   }
}

return nextfunk;
```