# Merge two array of objects based on a key

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays:

Array 1:

```
[
  { id: "abdc4051", date: "2017-01-24" }, 
  { id: "abdc4052", date: "2017-01-22" }
]
```

and array 2:

```
[
  { id: "abdc4051", name: "ab" },
  { id: "abdc4052", name: "abc" }
]
```

I need to merge these two arrays based on `id` and get this:

```
[
  { id: "abdc4051", date: "2017-01-24", name: "ab" },
  { id: "abdc4052", date: "2017-01-22", name: "abc" }
]
```

How can I do this without iterating trough `Object.keys`?

Comment: are the arrays always sorted and have the same index for the same `id`?

Comment: This is what I would do:

   `array1.map(x => {
        return array2.map(y => {
            if (y.id === x.id) {
                x.date = y.date;
                return x;
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: @Thadeus Ajayi - This is proper way than what the ticked answer provided..Just filling the missed braces as below

array1.map((x) =>
      array2.map((y) => {
        if (y.id === x.id) {
          x.date = y.date;
          return x;
        }
      })
    );

Comment: @ThadeusAjayi can you explain why you have x.date = y.date? what function does that serve? I don't know Array.map very well.

Comment: @Jknight I guess it should be x.name = y.name since that's the field that needs to be updated.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You can do it like this -

```js
let arr1 = [
    { id: "abdc4051", date: "2017-01-24" },
    { id: "abdc4052", date: "2017-01-22" }
];

let arr2 = [
    { id: "abdc4051", name: "ab" },
    { id: "abdc4052", name: "abc" }
];

let arr3 = arr1.map((item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, arr2[i]));

console.log(arr3);
```

---

*Use below code if `arr1` and `arr2` are in a different order:*

```js
let arr1 = [
  { id: "abdc4051", date: "2017-01-24" }, 
  { id: "abdc4052", date: "2017-01-22" }
];

let arr2 = [
  { id: "abdc4051", name: "ab" },
  { id: "abdc4052", name: "abc" }
];

let merged = [];

for(let i=0; i<arr1.length; i++) {
  merged.push({
   ...arr1[i], 
   ...(arr2.find((itmInner) => itmInner.id === arr1[i].id))}
  );
}

console.log(merged);
```

*Use this if `arr1` and `arr2` are in a same order*

```js
let arr1 = [
  { id: "abdc4051", date: "2017-01-24" }, 
  { id: "abdc4052", date: "2017-01-22" }
];

let arr2 = [
  { id: "abdc4051", name: "ab" },
  { id: "abdc4052", name: "abc" }
];

let merged = [];

for(let i=0; i<arr1.length; i++) {
  merged.push({
   ...arr1[i], 
   ...arr2[i]
  });
}

console.log(merged);
```

Comment: This is merging the arrays only? It does not "join" on arr1.id == arr2.id as OP has asked.

Comment: @Marty131 As per the OP's statement, I just assumed that the order of both the arrays are not in a scrambled state. If it is scrambled, then the code that I given wont work.

Comment: Title is “Merge two array of objects based on a key”. OP also mentions in post “based on id”.

Comment: Even though i agree with you guys on the title, it does pass the test case OP has written. Good for next time to write better test cases

Comment: This does not respect a key / key-value. It just merge every item from array. The question was: How to merge two arrays by key. For arr1 you have to find the correct item from arr2 by key "id".

Comment: @Dominik Updated the answer as per OP's requirement.

Comment: @Marty131 Addressed the exact issue of OP. Have a look at the updated code,.

Comment: Be careful one thing, the two arrays do have to have the exact same number of data and keys. If one has 2 key another has 3 key, it won't work.

Comment: @Daisy A simple conditional assignment would tackle that, `let arrayToBeIterated = arr1.length > arr2.length ? arr1 : arr2;`

Answer (score 75):

You can do this in one line

```js
let arr1 = [
    { id: "abdc4051", date: "2017-01-24" },
    { id: "abdc4052", date: "2017-01-22" }
];

let arr2 = [
    { id: "abdc4051", name: "ab" },
    { id: "abdc4052", name: "abc" }
];

const mergeById = (a1, a2) =>
    a1.map(itm => ({
        ...a2.find((item) => (item.id === itm.id) && item),
        ...itm
    }));

console.log(mergeById(arr1, arr2));
```

1. Map over array1
2. Search through array2 for array1.id
3. If you find it ...spread the result of array2 into array1

The final array will only contain id's that match from both arrays

Comment: great! what's the purpose of "&& item" in the find method?

Comment: @Fabrice my guess is that, when writing the answer, the (incorrect) assumption was that `[].find()` required the found item to be returned, rather than just a boolean. 
But since it's in the answer now, we can make up some use for it :-) Now it avoids a match if `item` is falsey. So it's a bit like a JOIN in a three-valued relational algebra such as SQL (won't equijoin on NULL). IOW, if the `id` is missing or falsey on either side, there's no match.

Comment: you don't need `&& item` here, `find` will return found element.
`...a2.find(item => item.id === itm.id),`

Comment: `&& item` not needed.  If there are no items, the predicate callback is never called, so why have it?

Answer (score 74):

This solution is applicable even when the merged arrays have different sizes.
Also, even if the matching keys have different names.

Merge the two arrays by using a Map as follows:

```js
const arr1 = [
  { id: "abdc4051", date: "2017-01-24" }, 
  { id: "abdc4052", date: "2017-01-22" },
  { id: "abdc4053", date: "2017-01-22" }
];
const arr2 = [
  { nameId: "abdc4051", name: "ab" },
  { nameId: "abdc4052", name: "abc" }
];

const map = new Map();
arr1.forEach(item => map.set(item.id, item));
arr2.forEach(item => map.set(item.nameId, {...map.get(item.nameId), ...item}));
const mergedArr = Array.from(map.values());

console.log(JSON.stringify(mergedArr));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Run the stack snippet to see the result:

```
[
  {
    "id": "abdc4051",
    "date": "2017-01-24",
    "nameId": "abdc4051",
    "name": "ab"
  },
  {
    "id": "abdc4052",
    "date": "2017-01-22",
    "nameId": "abdc4052",
    "name": "abc"
  },
  {
    "id": "abdc4053",
    "date": "2017-01-22"
  }
]
```

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted answer as it allows for different keys and different sized arrays

Comment: This also solved my problem as I had to combine on a property and still return the objects that did not combine.

Comment: This is the modern answer as of Feb 2022. @Adel / Op should really consider changing the accepted answer.

Comment: Perfect, this answer has time complexity of O(n) while if we were to use `map` and `find` or some other combination, it would be O(n^2). Thanks a lot, I totally forgot about using Map for this problem

Comment: I'd like to add it acts like a right outer join, in case you have ```status``` in both objects, arr1 has status:1 and arr2 has status 0, arr2 status will show up in the end result

Answer (score 12):

Here's an O(n) solution using reduce and Object.assign

```
const joinById = ( ...lists ) =>
    Object.values(
        lists.reduce(
            ( idx, list ) => {
                list.forEach( ( record ) => {
                    if( idx[ record.id ] )
                        idx[ record.id ] = Object.assign( idx[ record.id ], record)
                    else
                        idx[ record.id ] = record
                } )
                return idx
            },
            {}
        )
    )
```

To use this function for the OP's case, pass in the arrays you want to join to joinById (notice lists is a rest parameter).

```
let joined = joinById(list1, list2)
```

Each list gets reduced to a single object where the keys are ids and the values are the objects. If there's a value at the given key already, it gets object.assign called on it and the current record.

Here's the generic O(n*m) solution, where n is the number of records and m is the number of keys. This will only work for valid object keys. You can convert any value to base64 and use that if you need to.

```
const join = ( keys, ...lists ) =>
    lists.reduce(
        ( res, list ) => {
            list.forEach( ( record ) => {
                let hasNode = keys.reduce(
                    ( idx, key ) => idx && idx[ record[ key ] ],
                    res[ 0 ].tree
                )
                if( hasNode ) {
                    const i = hasNode.i
                    Object.assign( res[ i ].value, record )
                    res[ i ].found++
                } else {
                    let node = keys.reduce( ( idx, key ) => {
                        if( idx[ record[ key ] ] )
                            return idx[ record[ key ] ]
                        else
                            idx[ record[ key ] ] = {}
                        return idx[ record[ key ] ]
                    }, res[ 0 ].tree )
                    node.i = res[ 0 ].i++
                    res[ node.i ] = {
                        found: 1,
                        value: record
                    }
                }
            } )
            return res
        },
        [ { i: 1, tree: {} } ]
         )
         .slice( 1 )
         .filter( node => node.found === lists.length )
         .map( n => n.value )
```

This is essentially the same as the joinById method, except that it keeps an index object to identify records to join. The records are stored in an array and the index stores the position of the record for the given key set and the number of lists it's been found in.

Each time the same key set is encountered, it finds the node in the tree, updates the element at it's index, and the number of times it's been found is incremented.

After joining, the idx object is removed from the array with the slice and any elements that weren't found in each set are removed. This makes it an inner join, you could remove this filter and have a full outer join.

Finally each element is mapped to it's value, and you have the joined arrays.

Comment: This is my preferred answer to go. Thanks so much for the detailed analysis on each solution proposed.

Comment: Sorry, this answer is incomprehensible to me. - For one thing: where am I supposed to insert the two example arrays supplied by the original poster of the question?

Comment: @Henke My apologies for not explaining that. The two arrays get passed into the first function. You can copy and paste it, pass the two arrays in and the joined result gets returned. I'll update the answer with an example using the OP's data.

Answer (score 11):

You could use an arbitrary count of arrays and map on the same index new objects.

```js
var array1 = [{ id: "abdc4051", date: "2017-01-24" }, { id: "abdc4052", date: "2017-01-22" }],
    array2 = [{ id: "abdc4051", name: "ab" }, { id: "abdc4052", name: "abc" }],
    result = [array1, array2].reduce((a, b) => a.map((c, i) => Object.assign({}, c, b[i])));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Will you please help me to understand this line `result = [array1, array2].reduce((a, b) => a.map((c, i) => Object.assign({}, c, b[i])));` What is happening here ? Is it comparing two arrays and assigning the values which got common keys ?

Comment: it takes all arrays for joining and maps the result of an assigned single element of `a` (the whole array), later `c` as item with `b` and the item `b[i]`.

Comment: This code doesn't work when the ids are different or not in order
`var array1 = [{ id: "abdc4053", date: "2017-01-24" }, { id: "abdc4054", date: "2017-01-22" }],
    array2 = [{ id: "abdc4051", name: "ab" }, { id: "abdc4052", name: "abc" }],
    result = [array1, array2].reduce((a, b) => a.map((c, i) => Object.assign({}, c, b[i])));
    
console.log(result);`

Answer (score 10):

To merge the two arrays on `id`, assuming the arrays are equal length:

```
arr1.map(item => ({
    ...item,
    ...arr2.find(({ id }) => id === item.id),
}));
```

Answer (score 10):

If you have 2 arrays need to be merged based on values even its in different order

```
let arr1 = [
    { id:"1", value:"this", other: "that" },
    { id:"2", value:"this", other: "that" }
];

let arr2 = [
    { id:"2", key:"val2"},
    { id:"1", key:"val1"}
];
```

you can do like this

```
const result = arr1.map(item => {
    const obj = arr2.find(o => o.id === item.id);
    return { ...item, ...obj };
  });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 8):

We can use lodash here. _.merge works as you expected. It works with the common key present.

```
_.merge(array1, array2)
```

Answer (score 5):

Non of these solutions worked for my case:

- missing objects can exist in either array
- runtime complexity of O(n)

notes:

- I used lodash but it's easy to replace with something else
- Also used Typescript (just remove/ignore the types)

```
import { keyBy, values } from 'lodash';

interface IStringTMap<T> {
  [key: string]: T;
}

type IIdentified = {
  id?: string | number;
};

export function mergeArrayById<T extends IIdentified>(
  array1: T[],
  array2: T[]
): T[] {
  const mergedObjectMap: IStringTMap<T> = keyBy(array1, 'id');

  const finalArray: T[] = [];

  for (const object of array2) {
    if (object.id && mergedObjectMap[object.id]) {
      mergedObjectMap[object.id] = {
        ...mergedObjectMap[object.id],
        ...object,
      };
    } else {
      finalArray.push(object);
    }
  }

  values(mergedObjectMap).forEach(object => {
    finalArray.push(object);
  });

  return finalArray;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use array methods

```js
let arrayA=[
{id: "abdc4051", date: "2017-01-24"},
{id: "abdc4052", date: "2017-01-22"}]

let arrayB=[
{id: "abdc4051", name: "ab"},
{id: "abdc4052", name: "abc"}]

let arrayC = [];


  

arrayA.forEach(function(element){
  arrayC.push({
  id:element.id,
  date:element.date,
  name:(arrayB.find(e=>e.id===element.id)).name
  });  
});

console.log(arrayC);

//0:{id: "abdc4051", date: "2017-01-24", name: "ab"}
//1:{id: "abdc4052", date: "2017-01-22", name: "abc"}
```

Comment: The function `isBiggerThan10()` is just a left-over? Not really making any sense here?

Answer (score 4):

Here is one-liner (order of elements in array is not important and assuming there is 1 to 1 relationship):

```
var newArray = array1.map(x=>Object.assign(x, array2.find(y=>y.id==x.id)))
```

Comment: I have found that - in SQL terms - this answer produces a _left outer join_, given that `arr1` is the _left_ array (table) and `arr2` is the _right_ array.
(The original poster of the question has not clarified what type of join he would like as an
 answer.)

Answer (score 4):

I iterated through the first array and used the `.find` method on the second array to find a match where the `id` are equal and returned the result.

```js
const a = [{ id: "abdc4051", date: "2017-01-24" },{ id: "abdc4052", date: "2017-01-22" }];
const b = [{ id: "abdc4051", name: "ab" },{ id: "abdc4052", name: "abc" }];

console.log(a.map(itm => ({...itm, ...b.find(elm => elm.id == itm.id)})));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can recursively merge them into one as follows:

```js
function mergeRecursive(obj1, obj2) {
    for (var p in obj2) {
        try {
            // Property in destination object set; update its value.
            if (obj2[p].constructor == Object) {
                obj1[p] = this.mergeRecursive(obj1[p], obj2[p]);

            } else {
                obj1[p] = obj2[p];

            }

        } catch (e) {
            obj1[p] = obj2[p];

        }
    }
    return obj1;
}

arr1 = [
    { id: "abdc4051", date: "2017-01-24" },
    { id: "abdc4052", date: "2017-01-22" }
];
arr2 = [
    { id: "abdc4051", name: "ab" },
    { id: "abdc4052", name: "abc" }
];

mergeRecursive(arr1, arr2)
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Irrespective of the order you can merge it by,

```js
function merge(array,key){
    let map = {};
    array.forEach(val=>{
        if(map[val[key]]){
            map[val[key]] = {...map[val[key]],...val};
        }else{
            map[val[key]] = val;
        }
    })
    return Object.keys(map).map(val=>map[val]);
}

let b = [
  { id: "abdc4051", name: "ab" },
  { id: "abdc4052", name: "abc" }
];
let a = [
  { id: "abdc4051", date: "2017-01-24" }, 
  { id: "abdc4052", date: "2017-01-22" }
];

console.log(merge( [...a,...b], 'id'));
```

Comment: Good answer. However, to me the important thing is whether the order of the objects in the two arrays destroys anything or not, which you don't really test for in your example above. So I tried your solution in [a stack snippet of my own](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405422), and it turns out your solution works just fine in this respect as well. Thanks! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

An approach if both two arrays have non-intersect items.

```js
const firstArray = [
  { id: 1, name: "Alex", salutation: "Mr." },
  { id: 2, name: "Maria", salutation: "Ms." },
];

const secondArray = [
  { id: 2, address: "Larch Retreat 31", postcode: "123452" },
  { id: 3, address: "Lycroft Close 12D", postcode: "123009" },
];

const mergeArr = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const obj = {};

  arr1.forEach(item => {
    obj[item.id] = item;
  });

  arr2.forEach(item => {
    obj[item.id]
      ? (obj[item.id] = { ...obj[item.id], ...item })
      : (obj[item.id] = item);
  });

  return Object.values(obj);
};

const output = mergeArr(firstArray, secondArray);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 Solution for someone who lands on this page in hope of finding one

```py
def merge(studentDetails, studentMark, merge_key):
    student_details = {}
    student_marks = {}
    for sd, sm in zip(studentDetails, studentMark):
        key = sd.pop(merge_key)
        student_details[key] = sd

        key = sm.pop(merge_key)
        student_marks[key] = sm

    res = []
    for id, val in student_details.items():
        # Merge three dictionary together
        temp = {**{"studentId": id}, **val, **student_marks[id]}
        res.append(temp)
    return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Test Case 1
    studentDetails = [
        {"studentId": 1, "studentName": 'Sathish', "gender": 'Male', "age": 15},
        {"studentId": 2, "studentName": 'kumar', "gender": 'Male', "age": 16},
        {"studentId": 3, "studentName": 'Roja', "gender": 'Female', "age": 15},
        {"studentId": 4, "studentName": 'Nayanthara', "gender": 'Female', "age": 16},
    ]
    studentMark = [
        {"studentId": 1, "mark1": 80, "mark2": 90, "mark3": 100},
        {"studentId": 2, "mark1": 80, "mark2": 90, "mark3": 100},
        {"studentId": 3, "mark1": 80, "mark2": 90, "mark3": 100},
        {"studentId": 4, "mark1": 80, "mark2": 90, "mark3": 100},
    ]

    # Test Case 2
    array1 = [
        {"id": "abdc4051", "date": "2017-01-24"},
        {"id": "abdc4052", "date": "2017-01-22"}
    ]
    array2 = [
        {"id": "abdc4051", "name": "ab"},
        {"id": "abdc4052", "name": "abc"}
    ]

    output = merge(studentDetails, studentMark, merge_key="studentId")
    [print(a) for a in output]

    output = merge(array1, array2, merge_key="id")
    [print(a) for a in output]
```

Output

```
{'studentId': 1, 'studentName': 'Sathish', 'gender': 'Male', 'age': 15, 'mark1': 80, 'mark2': 90, 'mark3': 100}
{'studentId': 2, 'studentName': 'kumar', 'gender': 'Male', 'age': 16, 'mark1': 80, 'mark2': 90, 'mark3': 100}
{'studentId': 3, 'studentName': 'Roja', 'gender': 'Female', 'age': 15, 'mark1': 80, 'mark2': 90, 'mark3': 100}
{'studentId': 4, 'studentName': 'Nayanthara', 'gender': 'Female', 'age': 16, 'mark1': 80, 'mark2': 90, 'mark3': 100}
{'studentId': 'abdc4051', 'date': '2017-01-24', 'name': 'ab'}
{'studentId': 'abdc4052', 'date': '2017-01-22', 'name': 'abc'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is converting the best answer (jsbisht) into a function that accepts the keys as arguments.

```js
const mergeArraysByKeyMatch = (array1, array2, key1, key2) => {
  const map = new Map();
  array1.forEach((item) => map.set(item[key1], item));
  array2.forEach((item) =>
    map.set(item[key2], { ...map.get(item[key2]), ...item })
  );
  const merged = Array.from(map.values());

  return merged;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... assuming both arrays are of the same length, I would probably do something like this:

```
var newArr = []
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++ {
    if (array1[i].id === array2[i].id) {
      newArr.push({id: array1[i].id, date: array1[i].date, name: array2[i].name});
  }
}
```

Comment: My apologies, I missed the last line of your post. x_X

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this with a nested mapping of the two arrays and updating the initial array:

```
member.map(mem => {
return memberInfo.map(info => {
    if (info.id === mem.userId) {
        mem.date = info.date;
        return mem;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of solutions available for this, But, We can simply use `for` loop and `if` conditions to get merged arrays.

```
const firstArray = [
  { id: 1, name: "Alex", salutation: "Mr." },
  { id: 2, name: "Maria", salutation: "Ms." },
];

const secondArray = [
  { id: 1, address: "Larch Retreat 31", postcode: "123452" },
  { id: 2, address: "Lycroft Close 12D", postcode: "123009" },
];

let mergedArray: any = [];

for (const arr1 of firstArray) {
  for (arr2 doc of secondArray) {
    if (arr1.id === arr2.id) {
      mergedArray.push({ ...arr1, ...arr2 });
    }
  }
}

console.log(mergedArray)
```

Comment: What I concern about this code is the complexity because it is O^(n*m) and is not efficient with huge data sizes

Answer (score 0):

A Typescript O(n+m) (which could be classified as O(n)) solution; without lodash:

```js
// RequireAtLeastOne from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510611/typescript-interface-require-one-of-two-properties-to-exist/49725198#49725198
type RequireAtLeastOne<T, Keys extends keyof T = keyof T> = Pick<
  T,
  Exclude<keyof T, Keys>
> &
  {
    [K in Keys]-?: Required<Pick<T, K>> & Partial<Pick<T, Exclude<Keys, K>>>;
  }[Keys];

export const mergeDualArraysOnKey = <
  K extends PropertyKey,
  T extends RequireAtLeastOne<{ [f in PropertyKey]?: unknown }, K>
>(
  key: K,
  ...lists: [T[], T[]]
): T[] => {
  const lookup: { [key in string]: number } = {};
  return lists[0].concat(lists[1]).reduce((acc: T[], value: T, i: number) => {
    const lookupKey = `${value[key]}`;
    if (lookup.hasOwnProperty(lookupKey)) {
      acc[lookup[lookupKey]] = Object.assign({}, acc[lookup[lookupKey]], value);
    } else {
      acc.push(value);
      lookup[lookupKey] = acc.length - 1;
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
};
```

First concatenates the two arrays and then iterates through the newly created array. It uses a lookup table (object) to store the index of an item in the final merged array which has the same key and merges the objects inplace.

If this needed to be extended to handle more arrays, could use a loop or recursion as a wrapping function:

```js
const mergeArrays = <
  K extends PropertyKey,
  T extends RequireAtLeastOne<{ [f in PropertyKey]?: unknown }, K>
>(
  key: K,
  ...lists: T[][]
): T[] => {
  if (lists.length === 1) {
    return lists[0];
  }
  const l1 = lists.pop() || [];
  const l2 = lists.pop() || [];
  return mergeArrays(key, mergeDualArraysOnKey(key, l1, l2), ...lists);
};
```

with usage being:

```js
const arr1 = [
  { id: "abdc4052", date: "2017-01-22" },
  { id: "abdc4052", location: "US" },
  { id: "abdc4051", date: "2017-01-24" },
  { id: "abdc4053", date: "2017-01-24" },
  { id: "abdc4054", date: "2017-01-24" },
  { id: "abdc4055", location: "US" },
];

const arr2 = [
  { id: "abdc4052", date: "2017-01-22" },
  { id: "abdc4052", name: "abc" },
  { id: "abdc4055", date: "2017-01-24" },
  { id: "abdc4055", date: "2017-01-24", name: "abcd" },
];

const arr3 = [{ id: "abdc4056", location: "US" }];

const arr4 = [
  { id: "abdc4056", name: "abcde" },
  { id: "abdc4051", name: "ab--ab" },
];

mergeArrays<
    "id",
    {
      id: string;
      date?: string;
      location?: string;
      name?: string;
    }
  >("id", arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on your example, you can do it this way:

```js
const arrayOne = [
  { id: "abdc4051", date: "2017-01-24" }, 
  { id: "abdc4052", date: "2017-01-22" }
]

const arrayTwo = [
  { id: "abdc4051", name: "ab" },
  { id: "abdc4052", name: "abc" }
]

const mergeArrays = () => {
  arrayOne.forEach((item, i) => {
    const matchedFound = arrayTwo.findIndex(a => a.id === item.id);
    arrayOne[i] = {
      ...item,
      ...matchedFound,
    }
  });
};

mergeArrays();

console.log(arrayOne);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use simple JS here. Here is the simple step where you can generate the same output.

```js
const keyValuePair = function(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.map((item, index) => {
        return {...item, ...arr2[index]}
    });
}

console.log(keyValuePair([
    { id: "abdc4051", date: "2017-01-24" }, 
    { id: "abdc4052", date: "2017-01-22" }
  ], [
    { id: "abdc4051", name: "ab" },
    { id: "abdc4052", name: "abc" }
  ]))
```

Answer (score 0):

## ✅ TypeScript version here!

Below is a **more scalable solution** to the problem, because it allows you to **determine the key** based on which the arrays will be merged. The `callbackFn` is used to determine this key.

```
/**
 * Merges two arrays of objects (`arrayA` and `arrayB`) into one, resolving conflicts based on a key returned by the `callbackFn`.
 * For objects with the same key, properties from the objects in the second array (`arrayB`) overwrite those in the first (`arrayA`).
 *
 * @template TItem Extends object, the type of elements in the arrays to be merged.
 * @template TKey The type of the key used to identify unique objects.
 * @param {TItem[]} arrayA The first array of objects to merge.
 * @param {TItem[]} arrayB The second array of objects to merge.
 * @param {(value: TItem) => TKey} callbackFn A callback function that generates a key for each object based on its value. Used to identify and resolve conflicts between objects.
 * @returns {TItem[]} A new array containing merged objects from `arrayA` and `arrayB`. In case of conflicts, properties from `arrayB` objects take precedence.
 * @example
 *
 * const mergedArray = merge(
 *   [{ id: 1, name: "John" }, { id: 2, name: "Alice" }],
 *   [{ id: 1, age: 18 }, { id: 3, name: "Bob" }],
 *   (element) => element.id
 * );
 * // [{ id: 1, name: "John", age: 18 }, { id: 2, name: "Alice" }, { id: 3, name: "Bob" }]
 */
export function merge<TItem extends object, TKey>(
  arrayA: TItem[],
  arrayB: TItem[],
  callbackFn: (value: TItem) => TKey
): TItem[] {
  const map = new Map<TKey, TItem>();

  arrayA.forEach((item) => {
    const key = callbackFn(item);
    map.set(key, item);
  });
  
  arrayB.forEach((item) => {
    const key = callbackFn(item);
    const oldItem = resultMap.get(key);
    map.set(key, { ...oldItem, ...item });
  });
  
  return Array.from(map.values());
}
```

#### Usage:

Below is the use of this function for OP data:

```js
const arr1 = [
  { id: "abdc4051", date: "2017-01-24" },
  { id: "abdc4052", date: "2017-01-22" }
];

const arr2 = [
  { id: "abdc4051", name: "ab" },
  { id: "abdc4052", name: "abc" }
];

const mergedArray = merge(arr1, arr2, (item) => item.id)
console.log(mergedArray);
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a version when you have an object and an array and you want to merge them and give the array a key value so it fits into the object nicely.

```js
var fileData = [
    { "id" : "1", "filename" : "myfile1", "score" : 33.1 }, 
    { "id" : "2", "filename" : "myfile2", "score" : 31.4 }, 
    { "id" : "3", "filename" : "myfile3", "score" : 36.3 }, 
    { "id" : "4", "filename" : "myfile4", "score" : 23.9 }
];

var fileQuality = [0.23456543,0.13413131,0.1941344,0.7854522];

var newOjbect = fileData.map((item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, {fileQuality:fileQuality[i]}));

console.log(newOjbect);
```