# How to merge and order 2 arrays by specific ID

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to merge these 2 arrays by ID and sorted the merged result array by ID desc.

- Don't want to use any external lib like Lodash or Underscore
- Prefere to use **ES6** with a less lines of code as possible

.

```
const array1 = [
  {id: "14",  text: "Notice 14"},
  {id: "13",  text: "Notice 13"},
  {id: "12",  text: "Notice 12"},
  {id: "11",  text: "Notice 11"},
  {id: "10",  text: "Notice 10"},
]

const array2 = [ 
  {id: "11",  text: "Notice 11a"},
  {id: "14",  text: "Notice 14a"},
  {id: "12",  text: "Notice 12"},
  {id: "15",  text: "Notice 15"},
]
```

I want a merged array by ID and order by ID desc:

```
[
{id: "15",  text: "Notice 15"}
{id: "14",  text: "Notice 14a"}
{id: "13",  text: "Notice 13"}
{id: "12",  text: "Notice 12"}
{id: "11",  text: "Notice 11a"}
{id: "10",  text: "Notice 10"}
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge two array of objects based on a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849286/merge-two-array-of-objects-based-on-a-key)

Comment: Sorry but isn't the same answer. I need merge and ORDER array of objects.

Comment: There are many, many questions about ordering arrays of objects; [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1129216) is one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
Object
  .values([...array1, ...array2].reduce((acc, item) => ({ ...acc, [item.id]: item }), {}))
  .sort((a, b) => (b.id - a.id))
```

Comment: Sort doesn't exist on type '{}'

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution with `filter`, `concat`, and `sort` (assuming that values in `array2` override those in `array1`).

```js
const array1 = [
  {id: "14",  text: "Notice 14"},
  {id: "13",  text: "Notice 13"},
  {id: "12",  text: "Notice 12"},
  {id: "11",  text: "Notice 11"},
  {id: "10",  text: "Notice 10"}
];

const array2 = [ 
  {id: "11",  text: "Notice 11a"},
  {id: "14",  text: "Notice 14a"},
  {id: "12",  text: "Notice 12"},
  {id: "15",  text: "Notice 15"}
];

const merged = array1
                .filter(e => array2.find(a2e => a2e.id === e.id) === undefined)
                .concat(array2)
                .sort((a, b) => parseInt(b.id) - parseInt(a.id));
console.log(merged);
```

The idea is to filter elements in `array1` that are not in `array2` and then concatenate them with all elements in `array2` since that is the preferred array.

Note that this is not very efficient since we're interested in the least amount of code. We can improve performance by creating a set of id elements of `array2` so that we can replace the check `array2.find(a2e => a2e.id === e.id) === undefined` with a faster O(1) check.

Answer (score 0):

### Generic Solution for any number of arrays:

```js
function mergeArrays(...arrays){
    let obj = {};
    [].concat(...arrays).forEach(item => {
      obj[item.id] = item
    })
    
    return Object.values(obj)
}
```

### Breaking it down:

Considering you want only unique ids and the elements of second array are preferred in case of conflicts, this is how it can be done:

```js
function createObject(arr){
   let obj = {};
   arr.forEach(item => obj[item.id] = item )
   return obj;
}

function getArray(obj) {
  return Object.values(obj)
}


let mergedArray = getArray({
   ...createObject(array1), 
   ...createObject(array2) 
})
```

To explain it a bit further:

1) You convert both arrays into an object, where ids acts as the keys

2) when two objects are merged, conflicts are resolved by keeping the value of the second object

3) Finally, you reverse engineer the first step to get the final array back from the object format.

Answer (score 0):

Using modern Javascript, you can use a `Map` object to solve this problem.

```
const array1 = [
    {id: "14",  text: "Notice 14"},
    {id: "13",  text: "Notice 13"},
    {id: "12",  text: "Notice 12"},
    {id: "11",  text: "Notice 11"},
    {id: "10",  text: "Notice 10"}
];

const array2 = [ 
    {id: "11",  text: "Notice 11a"},
    {id: "14",  text: "Notice 14a"},
    {id: "12",  text: "Notice 12"},
    {id: "15",  text: "Notice 15"}
];


function merge(arr1, arr2) {
    // Use a Map to map objects by Id
    const map = new Map();
    arr1.forEach(e => map.set(e.id, e));
    arr2.forEach(e => map.set(e.id, e));

    // Create an empty array and populate it with the map entries
    const result = [];
    map.forEach( (value, key, map) => result.push(value));

    // Sort by ID desc
    result.sort((a, b) => a.id < b.id);
    return result;
}

console.log(merge(array1, array2));
```

This prints:

```
[ { id: '15', text: 'Notice 15' },
  { id: '14', text: 'Notice 14a' },
  { id: '13', text: 'Notice 13' },
  { id: '12', text: 'Notice 12' },
  { id: '11', text: 'Notice 11a' },
  { id: '10', text: 'Notice 10' } ]
```