# Javascript: Map values of two arrays in a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays of objects, that look like this:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    condition: 1,
    helpers: [{id: 1, condition: null}, {id: 2, condition: 2}]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    condition: null,
    helpers: [{id: 1, condition: 1}, {id: 2, condition: null}]
  }
]

const conds = [
  {
    id: 1,
    conditions: {
       rules: ['test', 'foo']
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    conditions: {
       rules: ['#hashtag', 'foo']
    }
  }
]
```

What I try to achieve is, that I want to replace the `condition` values of the `data` array with the ones in the `conds` array.

My solution, which does not work quite well looks like this:

```
let newArray = [];

data.forEach(obj => {
        conds.forEach(cond => {
            if (obj.condition) {
                if (obj.condition === cond.id) {
                    obj.condition = cond.conditions.rules;
                    newArray.push(obj);
                }
            } else {
                obj.helpers.forEach(h => {
                    if (h.condition && h.condition === cond.id) {
                        h.condition = cond.conditions.rules;
                        newArray.push(obj);
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    });
```

I feel like I am pretty close to the solution since my `newArray` contains the changes properties, but not for the last item inside of helpers, whereas the `condition` property is still 2.

The output should look like this:

```
[
  {
     id: 1
     condition: ['test', 'foo'],
     helpers: [{id: 1, condition: null}, {id: 2, condition: ['#hashtag', 'foo']}]
  },
  {
     id: 2
     condition: null,
     helpers: [{id: 1, condition: ['test', 'foo']}, {id: 2, condition: null}]
  },
]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is expected output format?

Comment: This looks a lot like https://stackoverflow.com/q/46849286/215552. You just need to loop over `data`, get `helpers`, and do the merge outlined in the answers to the question I've linked to.

Comment: @Eddie i added the output in the main question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working:

```
const finalData = data.map(dataItem => {
  dataItem.condition = dataItem.condition ? rulesMap[dataItem.condition] : null;
  dataItem.helpers.map(item => {
    item.condition = item.condition ? rulesMap[item.condition] : null
  })
  return dataItem;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the `data` array using **[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** get the `id` then filter the `conds` array with it using **[`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** to get the related `conditions.rules` like:

```
data.forEach(function(item) {
    item.condition = conds.find(x => x.id === item.id).conditions.rules;
});
```

**Working fiddle:**

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    condition: 1,
    helpers: [{id: 1, condition: null}, {id: 2, condition: 2}]
  },{
    id: 2,
    condition: null,
    helpers: [{id: 1, condition: 1}, {id: 2, condition: null}]
}];

const conds = [{
    id: 1,
    conditions: {
       rules: ['test', 'foo']
    }
  },{
    id: 2,
    conditions: {
       rules: ['#hashtag', 'foo']
    }
}];

data.forEach(function(item) {
  item.condition = conds.find(x => x.id === item.id).conditions.rules;
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Every time you use find, inside the loop, you create another loop. Imagine two giant arrays, it will take forever to finish.
I think mapping the conditions is the less expensive way of doing it as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: hey @zakaria, unfortunately this is not a working example. The conditions inside of the `helpers` array should also be mapped to the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    condition: 1,
    helpers: [{id: 1, condition: null}, {id: 2, condition: 2}]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    condition: null,
    helpers: [{id: 1, condition: 1}, {id: 2, condition: null}]
  }
]

const conds = [
  {
    id: 1,
    conditions: {
       rules: ['test', 'foo']
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    conditions: {
       rules: ['#hashtag', 'foo']
    }
  }
]

// START SOLUTION

const rulesMap = conds.reduce((map, condition) => {
    map[condition.id] = condition.conditions.rules;
    return map;
}, {});

const finalData = data.map(dataItem => {
    dataItem.condition = dataItem.condition ? rulesMap[dataItem.condition] : null;
    return dataItem;
});

// END SOLUTION

console.log(finalData);
```

Create a map of conditions:

```
const rulesMap = conds.reduce((map, condition) => {
    map[condition.id] = condition.conditions.rules;
    return map;
}, {});
```

Get the new data list with condition rules replaced:

```
const finalData = data.map(dataItem => {
    dataItem.condition = dataItem.condition ? rulesMap[dataItem.condition] : null;
    return dataItem;
});
```

Comment: I get the error `reduction is not defined` in this :/

Comment: I've just changed the map constructor to use less memory. `rulesMap` make smore sense here as we do not care about other properties.

Comment: hey @Bruno - this is unfortunately not the solution as I have expected. Please see the expected output in my question - actually your solution returns the same as my version. :/ The condition inside of the `helpers` array should also be mapped to the conditions.

Comment: Works with this logic using your rulesmap:


    ```const finalData = data.map(dataItem => {
        dataItem.condition = dataItem.condition ? rulesMap[dataItem.condition] : null;
 dataItem.helpers.map(item => {
  item.condition = item.condition ? rulesMap[item.condition] : null
        })
        return dataItem;
    });```