# Merge two arrays of arrays by ID in AppsScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have two arrays in an App Script project, one with a user email and their last login date, and one with their email and license type. I'd like to combine these two arrays into an array where each item has their email, last login, and license.

It's not guaranteed that the arrays will be in the same order.

Example:

```
Array 1: [[google.user@domain.com, Google-Apps, 1010020020],[google.user2@domain.com, Google-Apps, 1010020020]
Array 2: [[google.user2@domain.com, 12/31/1969],[google.user@domain.com, 12/31/1969]]
```

becomes

```
Array 3: [[google.user@domain.com, 12/31/1969, Google-Apps, 1010020020],[google.user2@domain.com, 12/31/1969, Google-Apps, 1010020020]]
```

I tried several of the methods described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849286/merge-two-array-of-objects-based-on-a-key) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480008/javascript-merging-objects-by-id) but they seem to be ES6 and throw errors when I run them.

Comment: Is the first array of Array 1 always the combine partner to Array 2? Or do you need to always need to check the 'google.user@domain.com' before merging?

Comment: For example, how about this? ``var Array3 = Array1.map(function(e, i){return Array2[i].concat(e)})``

Comment: @JonathanStellwag No, it could be in a random order and it would need to be checked. Will clarify in the post.

Comment: @Tanaike that didn't work unfortunately. It returned two (different) emails plus the information.

Comment: @Ian Hyzy Thank you for replying and the additional information. I'm glad your issue was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In es5, your code should be like this:

```
var a1 = [['google.user@domain.com', 'Google-Apps', '1010020020'],['google.user2@domain.com', 'Google-Apps', '1010020020']]
var a2 =[['google.user@domain.com', '12/31/1969'],['google.user2@domain.com', '12/31/1969
var a3 = new Array()
for(var i=0;i<a1.length;i++){ 
    a3[i]=new Array(); 
    a3[i][0]=a1[i][0]; 
    a3[i][2]=a1[i][1]; 
    a3[i][3]=a1[i][2]; 
}
for(var i=0;i<a2.length;i++){ 
    for(var j=0;i<a3.length;j++){ 
        if(a3[j][0] == a2[i][0]){ 
            a3[j][1] = a2[i][1]; 
            break; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Would this make sure that the emails match even if they aren't in order?

Comment: I get `TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined.` on the `if(a3[j][0] == a2[i][0]){` line

Comment: Don't forget this : var a3 = new Array();

Comment: I copied that line in as it appears in your example, yes. I'm pulling the data via the reports api and I think it may not be done yet. Will test this separately.

Comment: This did work, thanks! The issue I'm having is unrelated to the question so this solves it, thanks.

Comment: If your problem still exists, check this link:  https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FWXXZENEPUSI

Comment: I found a case for the failure - the arrays may not be the same length either. Can a case be added to put items without a match into a seperate array?

Comment: The answer depends on the case. You can make some changes in code to get a favorable result. Also you can use "lodash" library to write cleaner codes. Finaly, put your sample arrays here (if you want) and I will try to solve the problem.