# How to merge 2 different arrays of objects and return both matching and non matching items?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 different arrays I would like to merge.

```js
var arr1 = [ { cardId: 1001, knowCnt: 0, dknowCnt: 1 }, { cardId: 1002, knowCnt: 0, dknowCnt: 2 }, { cardId: 1003, knowCnt: 1, dknowCnt: 3 } ];

var arr2= [
  {
    cardId: 1001,
    videoId: "l4LjOvERDoM",
    startSeconds: 5,
    endSeconds: 10,
  },

  {
    cardId: 1002,
    videoId: "jsFVnf3iF3w",
    startSeconds: 5,
    endSeconds: 10,
  },

  {
    cardId: 1003,
    videoId: "dc0q0H9CO9k",
    startSeconds: 5,
    endSeconds: 10,
  },

  {
    cardId: 1004,
    videoId: "kdZe5ZjfNX4",
    startSeconds: 5,
    endSeconds: 10,
  }
];
```

The 2 arrays have a matching cardId and I would like the knowCnt and dknowCnt in arr1 to be added to their respective cardId properties in `arr2`. A potential solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849286/merge-two-array-of-objects-based-on-a-key) was:

```
    var mergeArrays = function() {
             var merged = [];

             const mergeById = (a1, a2) =>
                a1.map(itm => ({
                    ...a2.find((item) => (item.id === itm.id) && item), 
                    ...itm
                }));
            console.log(mergeById(arr1, arr2));
             }
      mergeArrays()
```

This works well but only returns the matching items. How can I return a single array with both the matching items (updated as above) but also including the remaining items from arr2. In other words the resulting array would look like arr2 but with 3 items updated from arr1? Note: the arrays may not be in matching order.

Thanks

Comment: olease add the result as well. what happens with matching objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a `Map` and filter `array2` by updateing know `cardId`.

```js
var array1 = [{ cardId: 1001, knowCnt: 0, dknowCnt: 1 }, { cardId: 1002, knowCnt: 0, dknowCnt: 2 }, { cardId: 1003, knowCnt: 1, dknowCnt: 3 }],
    array2 = [{ cardId: 1001, videoId: "l4LjOvERDoM", startSeconds: 5, endSeconds: 10 }, { cardId: 1002, videoId: "jsFVnf3iF3w", startSeconds: 5, endSeconds: 10 }, { cardId: 1003, videoId: "dc0q0H9CO9k", startSeconds: 5, endSeconds: 10 }, { cardId: 1004, videoId: "kdZe5ZjfNX4", startSeconds: 5, endSeconds: 10 }],
    references = array1.reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.cardId, o), new Map),
    filtered2 = array2.filter(o => {
        if (!references.has(o.cardId)) return true;
        Object.assign(references.get(o.cardId), o);
    });

console.log(array1);
console.log(filtered2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is nothing complicated, just concat arrays and make one object by desirable key... Very simple code

```
const res = [...arr1, ...arr2].reduce((agg, v) => {
   agg[v.cardId] = Object.assign(agg[v.cardId] || {}, v)   
   return agg
}, {})

console.log(res)
```