# Any way to solve this without concat this two arrays?

Tags: javascript

I need to get the expectedOutput array, which consists of the objects with the higher amount number. This code concat the two arrays and then reduce by higher amount. Im looking for a better way to do this, without concat. Thanks in advance.

```js
let arr1 = [{name: 'Almendras', amount: 0},{name: 'Nueces', amount: 0}, {name: 'Chocolate', amount: 0}];
let arr2 = [{name: 'Almendras', amount: 2}];

let expectedOutput = [{name: 'Almendras', amount: 2}, {name: 'Nueces', amount: 0}, {name: 'Chocolate', amount: 0}];

let concat = arr1.concat(arr2);

const output = Object.values(concat.reduce((x, y) => {
  x[y.name] = x[y.name] && x[y.name].amount > y.amount ? x[y.amount] : y
  return x
}, {}));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge two array of objects based on a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849286/merge-two-array-of-objects-based-on-a-key)

Comment: no, i dont need to merge arrays

Comment: ...So what's `arr1` and `arr2` in your example code?

Comment: Does the end result need to be a sorted array? Could it be an object as well?

Comment: "*without concat.*" - what's wrong with that?

Comment: Add into your question why you want to avoid concatenating the arrays, preferably with a concrete example.  You should have a good reason for it, and said reason will affect the answer.  It is likely that your concern is not important, you are misunderstanding the issues related to your question, and/or there is a better solution to your problem.

Comment: Your current code produces weird output if you swap the `amount` of the "Almendras" objects due to the expression `x[y.amount]` this should just be `x`.

Comment: Its for prevent bugs, sometimes arr2 is an empty array

Comment: @sonEtLumiere But `concat` handles empty arrays just fine. What bug are you referring to? Can you please post the input for the buggy case, where your code does not work as expected?

Comment: @sonEtLumiere empty arrays concat just fine though?  and even then you could just check arr2.length or typeof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid the `concat` call by running the `reduce` on both arrays individually:

```js
let arr1 = [{name: 'Almendras', amount: 0},{name: 'Nueces', amount: 0}, {name: 'Chocolate', amount: 0}];
let arr2 = [{name: 'Almendras', amount: 2}];

function mergeHigher(acc, el) {
  const old = acc[el.name];
  if (!old || el.amount >= old.amount) acc[el.name] = el;
  return acc;
}

const out1 = arr1.reduce(mergeHigher, {});
const out2 = arr2.reduce(mergeHigher, out1);

console.log(Object.values(out2));
```

Comment: Not that it actually matters, but why the use of `>=`?

Comment: @user120242 It's the negation of the `old.amount > el.amount` from the OPs code.