# Copy second nested array of objects into first nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, deep-copy, arrayobject

How can I assign key value from array of object to another array object

I would like to assign the `key:value` pair to the existing array of object from the another array of objects.

I have check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) but it is not working in my case.

I have tried something like this but that is not returning the desired output that I am looking for.

```js
const DataA = {
  "id": 57,
  "status": true,
  "options": [{ "id": 1, "name": "Type A" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Type B" },
    { "id": 3, "name": "Type C" }]
}

const DataB = {
  "id": 57,
  "status": true,
  "options": [{ "id": 1, "value": 10 },
    { "id": 2, "value": 20 },
    { "id": 3, "value": 30 }]
}

let result;
var A1 = DataA.options.map((v) => {
  console.log(v);
  result = v;
})

var A2 = DataB.options.map(v => {
  result.options = v;
  console.log("result",result);
})

let arr3 = DataA.options.map((item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, DataB[i]));

console.log(arr3);
```

Result will be I need as below:

```
const DataA = {
  "id": 57,
  "status": true,
  "options": [{ "id": 1, "name": "Type A", "value": 10 },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Type B", "value": 20 },
    { "id": 3, "name": "Type C", "value": 30 }]
}
```

I need to merge the deep clone of the array that is slightly different from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849286/merge-two-array-of-objects-based-on-a-key).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge two array of objects based on a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849286/merge-two-array-of-objects-based-on-a-key)

Comment: No, as I would like to do a deep merge of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked duplicate does actually address your question, but you need to adjust it to your situation and not just copy paste.

```
DataA.options = DataA.options.map((item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, DataB.options[i]));
```

but since this mutates the original `DataA` object anyway, you may as well just use `forEach()` and avoid creating the intermediate array from `.map()`.

```
DataA.options.forEach((item, i) => Object.assign(item, DataB.options[i]));
```

Both of the above assume that the `options` arrays of both objects are a. of the same length, and b. sorted by id. To avoid these assumptions you can use `.find()` to look for matching elements instead of relying on index.

```
DataA.options.forEach(item =>
  Object.assign(item, DataB.options.find(({ id }) => id === item.id)));
```

```js
const DataA = {
  "id": 57,
  "status": true,
  "options": [
    { "id": 1, "name": "Type A" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Type B" },
    { "id": 3, "name": "Type C" }]
}

const DataB = {
  "id": 57,
  "status": true,
  "options": [
    { "id": 1, "value": 10 },
    { "id": 2, "value": 20 },
    { "id": 3, "value": 30 }]
}

DataA.options.forEach(item =>
  Object.assign(item, DataB.options.find(({ id }) => id === item.id)));

console.log(DataA)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```