# Merge Array data using key as condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-apps-script

edited:

```
var arr1 = [{id=1}, {id=3]
var arr2 = [{id=1, text=1}, {id=2, text=2}, {id=4, text=4}]
```

I'm trying to merge the arr1 in the arr2 **except** when the key **id** value is the same.

This should be the output:

```
var arr3 = [{id=1, text=1}, {id=2, text=2}, {id=3, text=3}, {id=4, text=4}]
```

To do that I'm trying to use `if arr1.indexOf(arr2) !== 0` push values in arr3; but dosn't work.

```
var arr1 = [{id=1, text=1}, {id=3, text=3}]
var arr2 = [{id=1, text=1}, {id=2, text=2}, {id=4, text=4}]

var arr3 = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {

            if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i].id) !== 0) {
                arr3.push({
                  id: arr2[i].id, 
                  stars: arr2[i].text 
                  });
            }
        }
```

Any help?

Comment: In your script, `stars` of `stars: arr2[i].text` is `text`?

Comment: Possible duplicate, i would look for an answer to your question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849286/merge-two-array-of-objects-based-on-a-key

Also this is not valid JS:
`var arr1 = [{id=1}, {id=3]` -> `var arr1 = [{id:1}, {id:3}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `arr1.indexOf(arr2[i].id)` is always `-1`. Because each element of `arr1` is an object. In this case, `indexOf` cannot be directly used. So in this case, `arr2` is copied to `arr3`. And, the values of `arr1` are not used. I think that this might be the reason of your issue.
- In your question, you say that you want `var arr3 = [{id=1, text=1}, {id=2, text=2}, {id=3, text=3}, {id=4, text=4}]`. But in your script, it seems that the key is changed from `text` to `stars` like `stars: arr2[i].text`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script 1:

In this modified script, the values of `arr2` is merged to `arr1`.

```js
var arr1 = [{ id: 1, text: 1 }, { id: 3, text: 3 }];
var arr2 = [{ id: 1, text: 1 }, { id: 2, text: 2 }, { id: 4, text: 4 }];

for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
  if (!arr1.some(({id}) => id == arr2[i].id)) {
    arr1.push({id: arr2[i].id, text: arr2[i].text});
  }
}
arr1.sort((a, b) => a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1);
console.log(arr1)
```

- If `arr1.sort((a, b) => a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1);` is removed, the result array is not sorted as the ID.

#### Modified script 2:

As other sample script, how about the following script? In this modified script, the values of `arr2` and `arr2` are merged and removed the duplicated values.

```js
var arr1 = [{ id: 1, text: 1 }, { id: 3, text: 3 }];
var arr2 = [{ id: 1, text: 1 }, { id: 2, text: 2 }, { id: 4, text: 4 }];

var arr3 = [...arr1, ...arr2].reduce((ar, e) => {
  if (!ar.some(({id}) => id == e.id)) ar.push(e);
  return ar;
}, []).sort((a, b) => a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1);
console.log(arr3)
```

#### References:

- [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)