# How to compare two arrays and return another one?

Tags: javascript

How to compare two arrays and return another one?
I'm trying to compare two arrays to compare records by id and then render a new array

```
const arr1 = [
  { id: 1, title: "Admin" },
  { id: 2, title: "Vip" }
];

const arr2 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    root: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    root: 0
  }
];

let intersection = arr1.filter(({ id }) => arr2.includes(id));
```

***need:***

```
const needArr = [
  { id: 1, title: "Admin", root: 1 },
  { id: 2, title: "Vip", root: 0 }
];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? If you want to return any other array, why do you need to compare the first two?

Comment: Will arr1 always have a corresponding record in arr2?

Comment: I think combine two array is a better title.

Comment: You need to compare by id, which will be unchanged

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849286/merge-two-array-of-objects-based-on-a-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and iterate over the first array `arr1`:

```js
const needArr = arr1.map(entry => {
    const root = arr2.find(arr2Entry => entry.id === arr2Entry.id)?.root
    return {...entry, root: root}
} )
```

The `root` property will be set to `undefined` for each entry in the `needArr` result if there is no entry with the same `id` in `arr2` as in `arr1`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work,

```js
const giveNew = (a, b) => {
    let shorter, longer;
    if(a.length>b.length){
      longer = a;
      shorter = b;
    } else {
      longer = b;
      shorter = a;
    }
  
    return longer.map((v, i)=> {
      const matched = shorter.find(val=> val.id === v.id);
      if(matched){
          return {
          ...v, ...matched
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's a 1:1 relationship between the arrays - [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over one of the arrays, [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the corresponding object in the other array by its id, and then return a new updated object.

```js
const arr1=[{id:1,title:"Admin"},{id:2,title:"Vip"}],arr2=[{id:1,root:1},{id:2,root:0}];

const out = arr2.map(obj => {
  return {
    ...arr1.find(inner => inner.id === obj.id),
    root: obj.root
  };
});

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

As is pointed out in [Merge two array of objects based on a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849286/merge-two-array-of-objects-based-on-a-key), you can do this:

```
let intersection = arr1.map(item => ({...item, ...arr2.find(item2 => item.id === item2.id)}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this worked.

```js
const arr1 = [
    { id: 1, title: "Admin" },
    { id: 2, title: "Vip"}
  ];
  const arr2 = [
    {
      id: 1,
      root: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      root: 0
    }
  ];
for(var i=0 ;i < arr2.length; i++)
{
    objIndex = arr1.findIndex((obj => obj.id == arr2[i].id));
    arr1[objIndex].root = arr2[i].root;
}
console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Hope this satisfies your use case. This also works in the case where there is no 1:1 mappings.

```js
const arr1 = [
    { id: 1, title: "Admin" , root: 0 },
    { id: 2, title: "Vip" , root: 0 },
    { id: 100, title: "NotExistInArr2" , root: 0 }
  ];
  const arr2 = [
    {
      id: 1,
      root: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      root: 0
    },
    {
      id: 200,
      root: 0
    }
  ];

const consolidatedIds = arr1.map(a => a.id).concat(arr2.map(a => a.id));
//console.log(consolidatedIds);
const consolidatedDedupedIds = arrayUnique(consolidatedIds);
//console.log(consolidatedDedupedIds);

const needArr = consolidatedDedupedIds.map(entry => {
    const arr1Item = arr1.find(arr1Entry => entry === arr1Entry.id);
    const arr2Item = arr2.find(arr2Entry => entry === arr2Entry.id);

    return {...arr1Item, ...arr2Item}
} )

console.log(needArr)

//--- utility function
function arrayUnique(array) {
    var a = array.concat();
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; ++i) {
        for(var j=i+1; j<a.length; ++j) {
            if(a[i] === a[j])
                a.splice(j--, 1);
        }
    }

    return a;
}
```

Note: improvised version of other questions, inspired from other answers