# How merge two arrays based on the key value matches

Tags: javascript

I am calling two API's and I'm getting two responses with Array values I want to merge those two arrays based on the key-value(name) matches. can anyone help with this

**response one**

```
const items = [
    {
      date: "2016-01-11",
      data: [
        { name: "car", estimate: 1.94 },
        { name: "scooty", estimate: 0.73 },
        { name: "phone", estimate: 0.59 },
        { name: "laptop ", estimate: 0.59 }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

**response 2**

```
const value = [
    { name: "car", actual: 1.94 },
    { name: "scooty", actual: 0.73 },
    { name: "phone", actual: 0.19 },
    { name: "laptop ", actual: 1.79 }
  ];
```

I want to do like this can any help on this, please

```
const mergedArrays = [
    {
      date: "2016-01-11",
      data: [
        { name: "car", estimate: 1.94, actual: 1.94 },
        { name: "scooty", estimate: 0.73, actual: 0.73},
        { name: "phone", estimate: 0.93, actual: 0.19 },
        { name: "laptop ", estimate: 1.03, actual: 1.79 }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849286/merge-two-array-of-objects-based-on-a-key