# How to merge two arrays of objects in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have two arrays of objects that I need to merge together to only get one array of object.
There is a lot of objects, both have more than 500+ objects

This is an exemple of the structure of the two array of objects :

```js
let API = [
  {
    actif: true,
    id: 8,
    creation_user: "David",
    date_creation: "févr  4 2022 12:17PM",
    description: "A description",
    version: "v1r1"
  },
  {
    actif: true,
    id: 10,
    creation_user: "Julien",
    date_creation: "févr  10 2022 12:17PM",
    description: "A description",
    version: "v1r2"
  },
  {
    actif: false,
    id: 20,
    creation_user: "Tom",
    date_creation: "févr  10 2022 12:17PM",
    description: "A description",
    version: "v1r2"
  }
]

let Parameters = [
  {
    id: 10,
    name: "codeRR",
    type: "string"
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    name: "codeAA",
    type: "string"
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    name: "codeCC",
    type: "string"
  }
]
```

As we can see, they both have an ID, this ID is the same in both arrays.
But not everytime, API can have no parameter.

What i'm trying to achieve is to get in the second array, the "name" and "type", and to add it to the first array (or in a new array).

I've tried with .map on the first array (also tried with the second one) :

```js
let Ressource = api.map(item => Object.assign({}, item, parametre.find(target => target.id === item.id)));
 
 // Result of Ressource
 
 [
  {
    actif: true,
    id: 8,
    creation_user: "David",
    date_creation: "févr  4 2022 12:17PM",
    description: "A description",
    version: "v1r1";
    name: "codeRR",
    type: "string
  }
 ]
 
 // Want I want :
 [
  {
    actif: true,
    id: 8,
    creation_user: "David",
    date_creation: "févr  4 2022 12:17PM",
    description: "A description",
    version: "v1r1",
    parameter: [
      {
        name: "codeRR",
        type: "string
      },
      {
        name: "codePP",
        type: "string
      }
    ]
  }
 ]
```

But when an API have multiple parameter it overwrite the previous one.
Is it possible to make something like this in my API

```
parameter: [{"name": "codeRR", type: "string"}, {"name": "codePP", "type": "string"}]
```

Comment: **A)** `id = 8` is present in `API` but not present in `Parameters` array. So, how do we get the resulting `Resource` to have `name: codeRR` for `id = 8`? **B)** Would you please update the question with what is expected result for `id = 20`?.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript merging objects by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480008/javascript-merging-objects-by-id)

Comment: yes, id = 8 is not present in Parameters because sometime API doesn't have a parameter, I will edit my question.

Comment: also [Merge two array of objects based on a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849286/merge-two-array-of-objects-based-on-a-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Group the `Parameters` array by their `id` using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), this would give an object where the keys are the `id`s and the values are an array of parameter objects.
2. Loop over the `API` array and using the object created above add the `parameter` property wherever the parameter information is available.

```js
let 
  API = [
    { actif: true, id: 8, creation_user: "David", date_creation: "févr  4 2022 12:17PM", description: "A description", version: "v1r1" },
    { actif: true, id: 10, creation_user: "Julien", date_creation: "févr  10 2022 12:17PM", description: "A description", version: "v1r2" },
    { actif: false, id: 20, creation_user: "Tom", date_creation: "févr  10 2022 12:17PM", description: "A description", version: "v1r2" },
  ],
  Parameters = [
    { id: 10, name: "codeRR", type: "string" },
    { id: 20, name: "codeAA", type: "string" },
    { id: 20, name: "codeCC", type: "string" },
  ],
  ParametersGroup = Parameters.reduce((r, p) => ((r[p.id] ??= []).push(p), r), {}),
  APIWithParams = API.map((o) => ({
    ...o,
    ...(ParametersGroup[o.id] && { parameters: ParametersGroup[o.id] }),
  }));

console.log(APIWithParams);
```

If you want to handle single parameter and multiple parameters differently, then refer to the solution below:

```js
let 
  API = [
    { actif: true, id: 8, creation_user: "David", date_creation: "févr  4 2022 12:17PM", description: "A description", version: "v1r1" },
    { actif: true, id: 10, creation_user: "Julien", date_creation: "févr  10 2022 12:17PM", description: "A description", version: "v1r2" },
    { actif: false, id: 20, creation_user: "Tom", date_creation: "févr  10 2022 12:17PM", description: "A description", version: "v1r2" },
  ],
  Parameters = [
    { id: 10, name: "codeRR", type: "string" },
    { id: 20, name: "codeAA", type: "string" },
    { id: 20, name: "codeCC", type: "string" },
  ],
  ParametersGroup = Parameters.reduce((r, p) => ((r[p.id] ??= []).push(p), r), {}),
  APIWithParams = API.map((o) => {
    const paramsForId = ParametersGroup[o.id];
    return {
      ...o,
      ...(paramsForId && (paramsForId.length > 1 ? { parameters: paramsForId } : paramsForId[0])),
    };
  });

console.log(APIWithParams);
```

**Note:** Finding the parameter for an `id` again and again is *not* optimal. Hence we've created an object beforehand and referenced it while adding the parameter information.

**Other relevant documentations:**

- [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)
- [Comma operator (,)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Comment: Thanks you for the documentation, I truly need it, always having a bad time performing such merge and arrays of objects in general.

Comment: @Quentin I've also added a *note* in my answer, I'd recommend going through that. Since you mentioned that the arrays could be large, it's *not* optimal to `find` or `filter` (_or anything that takes linear time_) again and again.

Comment: I see, again, thanks you, I was a bit concerned about performance since it's was taking some time to build the array with a `find` or `filter`. Will read and take note from your links !

Comment: By the way, is there any optimal way to display all of the array ?

Comment: You want to render thousands of items at once? Usually that's *not* required and only a portion of the data is rendered at once. But in case you want to render everything at once, you can.

Comment: Well, it's not everything, but the majority of it. Like i'm displaying every api with every parameters.

Comment: @Quentin Okay, you can render everything that shouldn't be a problem but make sure you opt out of unnecessary re-renders by memoizing the component that renders all these items.

Answer (score 1):

If the parameters have the same attributes they will be overwritten.

if you need both of them you need to store them in an array

like this

```js
const decorate = (data, parameters) => data.map(d => ({...d, parameters: parameters.filter(({id}) => d.id === id)}))




let API = [
  {
    actif: true,
    id: 8,
    creation_user: "David",
    date_creation: "févr  4 2022 12:17PM",
    description: "A description",
    version: "v1r1"
  },
  {
    actif: true,
    id: 10,
    creation_user: "Julien",
    date_creation: "févr  10 2022 12:17PM",
    description: "A description",
    version: "v1r2"
  },
  {
    actif: false,
    id: 20,
    creation_user: "Tom",
    date_creation: "févr  10 2022 12:17PM",
    description: "A description",
    version: "v1r2"
  }
]

let Parameters = [
  {
    id: 10,
    name: "codeRR",
    type: "string"
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    name: "codeAA",
    type: "string"
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    name: "codeCC",
    type: "string"
  }
]

console.log(decorate(API,Parameters ))
```

Comment: Solved my problems with your code, so `filter` was far better than just a `find`. And yes, i need both, making sure I don't miss something

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. You can add extra logic for your `map` to handle multiple and single parameters separately.

```js
let API = [{
    actif: true,
    id: 8,
    creation_user: "David",
    date_creation: "févr  4 2022 12:17PM",
    description: "A description",
    version: "v1r1"
  },
  {
    actif: true,
    id: 10,
    creation_user: "Julien",
    date_creation: "févr  10 2022 12:17PM",
    description: "A description",
    version: "v1r2"
  },
  {
    actif: false,
    id: 20,
    creation_user: "Tom",
    date_creation: "févr  10 2022 12:17PM",
    description: "A description",
    version: "v1r2"
  }
]

let Parameters = [{
    id: 10,
    name: "codeRR",
    type: "string"
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    name: "codeAA",
    type: "string"
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    name: "codeCC",
    type: "string"
  }
]

const result = API.map((data) => {
  const updatedData = Object.assign({}, data)
  const foundParameters = Parameters.filter(({
    id
  }) => id === data.id)
  if (foundParameters.length === 0) {
    return data
  }

  if (foundParameters.length === 1) {
    return Object.assign(updatedData, foundParameters[0])
  } else {
    return Object.assign(updatedData, {
      parameter: foundParameters.map(({
        name,
        type
      }) => ({
        name,
        type
      }))
    })
  }
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I never thought about this extra logic, I take note !