# How to can I do this array desctructure with condition?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am facing one problem with array destructuring, Please read my questions-

This is array 1-

```
const Array1 = [
    {
        label: "Fashion",
        value: 1
    },
    {
        label: "Electronics",
        value: 2
    }
]
```

This is array2-

```
const Array2 = [
    {
        id: 1,
        values: [
            { value: "S", meta: "s" },
            { value: "M", meta: "m" },
            { value: "Xl", meta: "xl" },
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        values: [
            { value: "Red", meta: "red" },
            { value: "Yellow", meta: "yellow" },
            { value: "Green", meta: "green" },
        ]
    }
]
```

I have to combine this two array when `Id(array2)` matched to `value(array1)` and also change field label- like I need actually like this-

```
const Array3 = [
    {
        name: "Fashion",
        options: [
            { value: "S", label: "s" },
            { value: "M", label: "m" },
            { value: "Xl", label: "xl" },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Electronics",
        options: [
            { value: "Red", label: "red" },
            { value: "Yellow", label: "yellow" },
            { value: "Green", label: "green" },
        ]
    }
]
```

I have already tried in this way-

```
const Array3 = Array1.map((item) => {
    return {
        name: item.label,
        values: [],
        options: Array2.map((e: any) => {
            if (e.id === item.value) {
                return e.values.map((v: any) => {
                    return {
                        label: v.meta,
                        value: v.value
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
})
```

From this function I am getting - one extra field with `undefined`-

[Please click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSrx1.png)

But it's not working. Please help me by giving a correction of my functions.

Comment: you are using Array3 as an iterator for your second loop, this looks lke an error ;)

Comment: I update my questions.

Comment: I actually I write `Array2` in my code editor. But unfortunately it got `Array3` when placing my questions. That's why I update my questions. But my problems are still occurring.

Comment: It seems your requirement is that the options array in Array3 would be the same as values in Array2. So simply options: Array2.find(e => e.id === item.value).values would work. Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, but  `values` filed name have to be changed.

Comment: How can I do that.

Comment: `Array2.find(e => e.id === item.value).values` this will return `value` and `meta` field But I have to return it as `value` and `label`

Comment: Oh my bad I missed that. So, the reason why Array2.map doesn't work is that map function always returns the same number of elements as the array you run .map on. So adding a condition results in undefined elements when condition doesn't match. You can do this. Array2.find(e => e.id === item.value).values.map(v => { return { value: v.value, label: v.meta } })

Comment: Yes, yes, thanks. many many thanks. it working. Can place a answer. I want to accept your answer.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Have posted the answer. Take a look at @Nina Scholz's answer too as it's more efficient

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge two array of objects based on a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849286/merge-two-array-of-objects-based-on-a-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `Array2.map` doesn't work is that map function always returns the same number of elements as the array you run `.map` on. So adding a condition results in undefined elements when condition doesn't match. You can do this:

```
options: Array2.find(e => e.id === item.value).values.map(v => { 
  return { value: v.value, label: v.meta } 
})
```

While this works, I'd recommend taking a look at @Nina Scholz's answer too as it makes use of Object/Dictionary which is much more efficient than running `.find` on Array2. O(1) vs O(n). So, if you expect to have lots of elements in Array2 or run this quite frequently then the more efficient solution would help

Comment: This is great!!

Answer (score 4):

You could take an object for the names and map new objects with `name` instead of `id` as properties.

```js
const
    array1 = [{ label: "Fashion", value: 1 }, { label: "Electronics", value: 2 }], 
    array2 = [{ id: 1, values: [ { value: "S", meta: "s" }, { value: "M", meta: "m" }, { value: "Xl", meta: "xl" }] }, { id: 2, values: [{ value: "Red", meta: "red" }, { value: "Yellow", meta: "yellow" }, { value: "Green", meta: "green" }] }],
    names = Object.fromEntries(array1.map(({ label, value }) => [value, label])),
    result = array2.map(({ id, values }) => ({
        name: names[id],
        options: values.map(({ meta: label, ...o }) => ({ ...o, label }))
    }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I would do the same. But i would use a Map<string, number> for names obj. But I would like to know what delivers the better performance Map vs. Object.fromEntries ?

Comment: Please read my questions again. Here your function return `value` and `meta` in values field. But I have to return `value` and `label` in values. I have to change field name `meta` to `label`.

Comment: @MdAli, please see edit.

Comment: @J1n, both options are possible. actually, i think `object` is faster, but i might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
const Array3 = Array1.map(array1Item => {
    const foundIndex = Array2.findIndex(array2Item => array2Item.id === array1Item.value);
    if(foundIndex !== -1) {
        return {
            name: array1Item.label,
            options: Array2[foundIndex].values
        }    
    };
    
    return undefined;
});
console.log(Array3);
/** 
[{
name: "Fashion"
options: Array(3)
0: {value: 'S', meta: 's'}
1: {value: 'M', meta: 'm'}
2: {value: 'Xl', meta: 'xl'}
},{
name: "Electronics"
options: Array(3)
0: {value: 'Red', meta: 'red'}
1: {value: 'Yellow', meta: 'yellow'}
2: {value: 'Green', meta: 'green'}
}]
*/
```

Comment: Please read my questions again. Here your function return `value` and `meta` in values field. But I have to return `value` and `label` in values. I have to change field name `meta` to `label`.