# searching for characters within a JavaScript property name

Tags: javascript

I'm relatively new to JavaScript so please forgive me if this is silly/impossible, but I'm trying to standardize names of properties within a JavaScript object.  For example, I have code such as

```
var object = {
    "firstName": "Joe",
    "MiddleName": "Roy",
    "last_name": "Fool"
}
```

I want to make a new object that has property names firstName, middleName, and lastName.  Is there any way to search through these properties and see which ones are in violation?  Otherwise, I could always just make a total copy but that would be quite inefficient.  Thanks

Comment: "*I want to make a new object*" is always a total copy, what else did you have in mind?

Comment: You don't know know which ones are in violation necessarily, correct?  You're looking for some kind of linguistic parser?

Comment: This question answers how to iterate trought property names of an object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object

Comment: exactly, a linguistic parser would be a good way to put it

Comment: This fiddle would work for your example, but it would not change lastname to lastName http://jsfiddle.net/hAMWx/ but it's a start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be going beyond what you're looking for, but it's pretty easy to convert your underscore-separated naming to camelcase; you can iterate over your object and produce a new object with the correct names:

```
var converter = /_(\w)/g, lowerFirst = /^(\w)/;
function convertName(name) {
  if (converter.test(name)) {
    name = name.toLowerCase().replace(converter, function ($0, $1) {
             return $1.toUpperCase();
           });
  } else {
    // correct a first letter being uppercase
    name = name.replace(lowerFirst, function ($0, $1){ return $1.toLowerCase(); });
  }

  return name;
}

var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
    toString = Object.prototype.toString;

function isPlainObject(obj) {
  return toString.call(obj) === '[object Object]';
}


function convertObject(obj) {
  var k, output = {};
  for(k in obj) {
    if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, k)) {
      output[convertName(k)] = isPlainObject(obj[k]) ? convertObject(obj[k]) : obj[k];
    }
  }

  return output;
}
```

If the property names are already in camelcase, they won't be changed by the regexp.

Comment: This doesn't fix `convertName('MiddleName'); // "MiddleName"`

Comment: This wasn't in OPs example, but also you'll get `convertName('MIDDLE_NAME'); // "mIDDLENAME"`

Comment: tried to be a bit more robust by testing for underscore first; hard to write code too much beyond OP's examples since totally wrong camelcase input is hard/impossible to correct with a regexp

Comment: The only formats I have coming in are upper case first letter, camel case, and subscript...I'm thinking that somehow I may be able to run the first letters of these properties through a lower-case parser after I take care of the subscript

Comment: @ablackman93 if those are your only cases then `convertName` should work

Comment: You seem to be missing a `)` from `if (converter.test(name) {`

Comment: Hmm...I just realized that I need to make this recursive because I am dealing with attributes such as addresses which are in themselves objects that contain attributes (which must go by the same naming convention).  I suppose I could just insert an if statement after the for(k in obj) to check if 'k' is an object and then call convertObject on 'k' itself?

Answer (score 0):

By your example, one quick way is to map values of properties to a second object with a dictionary to choose the property names, obtained by (for example) [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)

```
var object = {"firstName": "Joe", "MiddleName": "Roy", "last_name": "Fool"};

var p = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object), // ["firstName", "MiddleName", "last_name"]
    dict = {
        'firstname': 'firstName',
        'first_name': 'firstName',
        'middlename': 'middleName',
        'middle_name': 'middleName',
        'lastname': 'lastName',
        'last_name': 'lastName'
    },
    o2 = {}, i;

for (i = 0; i < p.length; ++i) {
    o2[dict[p[i].toLowerCase()] || p[i]] = object[p[i]];
}

o2; // {firstName: "Joe", middleName: "Roy", lastName: "Fool"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do something like this.

The first `replace` can be used to replace any characters that you want to be markers for upper cased camel casing.

The second `replace` performs the camel casing on the letter that follows the marker.

The final `replace` makes sure that the first letter of the identifier is lower case.

`standardiseProperties` works on the `object` in place using the rules of `camelCase`. But you could just as well have it return the new object `standardised`.

If a name can not be used as it already exists, then the original name is used.

I didn't spend much time on this and there could well be optimisations, or you may wish to change the rules somewhat.

Javascript

```
function camelCase(string) {
    return string.replace(/[-+]/g, "_").replace(/_([\da-z])/gi, function (all, letter) {
        return letter.toUpperCase();
    }).replace(/^([A-Z])/, function (all, letter) {
        return letter.toLowerCase();
    });
}

function standardiseProperties(object) {
    var standardised = {},
        newName,
        i;

    for (i in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            newName = camelCase(i);
            if (standardised.hasOwnProperty(newName)) {
                standardised[i] = object[i];
            } else {
                standardised[newName] = object[i];
            }

            delete object[i];
        }
    }

    for (i in standardised) {
        object[i] = standardised[i];
    }
}

var object = {
    "firstName": "Joe",
    "MiddleName": "Roy",
    "last_name": "Fool"
};

console.log(object);
standardiseProperties(object);
console.log(object);
```

Output

```
Object {firstName: "Joe", MiddleName: "Roy", last_name: "Fool"}
Object {firstName: "Joe", middleName: "Roy", lastName: "Fool"}
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Frng2/)