# Having trouble walking JSON structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json structure that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "coordinates": [
            75.71027043,
            26.88661823
        ]
    },
    {
        "coordinates": [
            75.71027043,
            26.88661823
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm trying to access the coordinates so that I can feed them into a google maps API latlng.

```
function loadTweets(results) {
    var tweetStructure = $.parseJSON(results);
    console.log(tweetStructure);
    for (a in tweetStructure){
      console.log(a);
      for (coords in a){
        console.log(coords);
      }
    }

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0],coords[1]);
```

Whenever I try and walk the structure with this code I end up with the keys instead of the values (I think). Can anyone point out what I'm doing incorrectly?

Here's what I'm getting back:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
coordinates: Array[2]
__proto__: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
length: 6
__proto__: Array[0]

0 
0 
1 
0
```

Comment: Ya tell us what coords is. Im guessing thats the json object?

Comment: @arkonautom added the results

Comment: Have a look at the MDN documentation about `for...in` (especially the examples): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enumerate the properties of a javascript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Note: Your problem has nothing to do with JSON. *How* you got the data is irrelevant to the problem (which is how to iterate over object properties).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
             var tweetStructure = $.parseJSON(results);
                for (a in tweetStructure){
                    var co_arr = tweetStructure[a];
                  for (coords in co_arr.coordinates){
                    console.log(co_arr.coordinates[coords]);
                  }
            }
```