# JS - Constructor referencing

Tags: javascript, function, properties, constructor, alias

**TLDR:** How can you get the contents of a constructor/properties without actually knowing what it contains?

Given the following:

```
    function f(args) {
        this.defaults {
            param1 : 100,
            param2 : 900;
        };
        this.ranges {
            param1 : { min : 0, max : 500 },
            param2 : { min : 0, max : 1000 };
        };
    }
    var myF = new f();
```

The `defaults` and `ranges` can be accessed through the `myF.defaults.param1` and `myF.ranges.param1.min` calls. What if you do not know the name of the `defaults` or the `ranges`? How can you get the names and values within the `defaults` property without knowing them?

Example: Three of the above function; one like shown, F#2 with `param37`/`param42` and F#3 with `param68`/`param94`. How can you call F#2 and return or find out it contains `param37`/`param42` and their values?

**NOTE:** Obviously defining `ranges` without defining `defaults` would make no sense and be bad coding, which is why I angled the question towards getting the `defaults` and not both.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: and [How do I enumerate the properties of a javascript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/85992/218196)

Comment: The second one answered it. I had looked right at this and somehow completely ignored the answers for propertyName. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[How do I enumerate the properties of a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)

The answers in here solved it and this was a duplicate by my own error. Thanks.