# How to iterate through a nested object in a JSON with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this JSON:

```
{ 
    "USD" : {"15m" : 559.07, "last" : 559.07, "buy" : 559.07, "sell" : 562.39,  "symbol" : "$"},
    "CNY" : {"15m" : 3431.69912796, "last" : 3431.69912796, "buy" : 3431.69912796, "sell" : 3452.0780449199997,  "symbol" : "¥"}
}
```

Using nodejs, I've been trying to iterate through and return any of the members of the nested object. Assuming I wanted to get the member "last", I tried the following. However, I get "undefined". How should I access these members correctly?

```
        var bcData = JSON.parse(body);
        for (var key in bcData) {
            console.log(key + ": " + key.last + '\n');
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enumerate the properties of a javascript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object is still bcData. You need to first access key of bcData and then it's last property -

```
for (var key in bcData) {
    console.log(key + ": " + bcData[key].last + '\n');
}
```