# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '123' in

Tags: javascript, json, substring, keyvaluepair

Hi i have converted json object to string by using JSON.stringify now i want key value pair in array
for eg. key =en value =Anglais and so on...
here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skhurams/JVf8W/) 
code

```
      var data ={"en":{"name":"Anglais"},"fr":{"name":"Français"},
"it":{"name":"Italien"},"de":{"name":"Allemand"},"es":{"name":"Espagnol"}}
```

I have done so far

```
      var data = {
      "en": {
          "name": "Anglais"
      },
      "fr": {
          "name": "Français"
      },
          "it": {
          "name": "Italien"
      },
      "de": {
          "name": "Allemand"
      },
      "es": {
          "name": "Espagnol"
      }
  };
  var strData = JSON.stringify(data);
  for (var i = 0; i < strData.length; i++) {
      $('#dvarray').append('string array==' + strData[i] + "<br>");
  }
  $.each(strData, function (key, value) {

      var abbr = JSON.stringify(value);

       $('#dvstring').html('abbr=' + abbr.substr(2, 4)); //Uncaught TypeError:

  });
```

Comment: *"i have converted json object to string by using JSON.stringify"* I think you mean "JavaScript object to JSON". JSON can only exist in JavaScript in form of a string, so your statement makes little sense. What is `strData`? It sounds like you are trying to use `$.each` on something that is not an object.

Comment: i have updated my code now please help you can check in jsfiddle i want en, fr , de , es from string

Comment: Ok. As I expected, you are trying to to use `$.each` on a string. You can't do that. `$.each` is for arrays and objects. Please read the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/. It seems like you actually want to iterate over the data in the original object, so imply don't convert it to JSON.

Comment: can you update jsfiddle code i am still having problem

Comment: i can get key = name and value = Anglais but the problem is i cant get "en" , "fr" , "it", "de" , "es" cause it dont have key

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json) to learn how to work with objects.

Comment: i know how to iterate through javascript or jquery when you have key and value but if you dont have key then what??

Comment: ok i got it but now one problem i can get en fr etc separate from data.name can you help i want key as en and value as anglais etc you can check jsfiddle i have updated it

Comment: See also [How do I enumerate the properties of a javascript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/85992/218196)

Comment: thanks for the help i really appriciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this helped me

```
  var data = {
      "en": {
          "name": "Anglais"
      },
      "fr": {
          "name": "Français"
      },
          "it": {
          "name": "Italien"
      },
      "de": {
          "name": "Allemand"
      },
      "es": {
          "name": "Espagnol"
      }
  };

for(var prop in data) {
   $('#dvstring').append( prop + "    <>     " + data[prop].name +  "<br>") ;
}
  $.each(strData, function (key, value) {

      var abbr = JSON.stringify(value);

       $('#dvstring').append('abbr=' + abbr.substr(2, 4));     
  });
```