# iterate json array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

hi i have generated following json , can i iterate through this 
i have validated this josn using some sites

following is just example there can be more section like  MATHS, LOGICAL REASONING ,ENGLISH

they can also have their individual types

```
 {    "MATHS": [
    {
        "Section": "MATHS",
        "Type": "INCORRECT",
        "Count": "5"
    },
    {
        "Section": "MATHS",
        "Type": "NOT SOLVED",
        "Count": "20"
    }
],
"LOGICAL REASONING": [
    {
        "Section": "LOGICAL REASONING",
        "Type": "CORRECT",
        "Count": "1"
    },
    {
        "Section": "LOGICAL REASONING",
        "Type": "INCORRECT",
        "Count": "4"
    },
    {
        "Section": "LOGICAL REASONING",
        "Type": "NOT SOLVED",
        "Count": "20"
    }
]
 }
```

i have searched on may question on stack overflow but none of them can help me

Comment: and probably [How do I enumerate the properties of a javascript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/85992/218196)

Comment: and maybe [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4935632/218196)

Comment: From 1st link i can get only MATHS not count or other things, before criticising just take overview of problem , those questions are diffrent in all manner from this

Comment: No, they are not different at all. They explain how to go from JSON to an object (containing arrays) and how to access (nested) objects and arrays. All you have to do is put the pieces together.

Comment: @FelixKling if you think yourself smart can make one fiddle for me for this

Comment: Maybe this helps to get started: `for (var prop in data) { for (var i = 0; i < data[prop].length; i++) { console.log(data[prop][i]); } }`. `data` is your object, parsed from JSON. This iterates over all the objects in the array and you can access properties you want. This btw is explained in [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json), section "What if the property names are dynamic and I don't know them beforehand?".

Comment: @FelixKling http://jsfiddle.net/A8e3G/  not working

Comment: Works fine for me. Did you have a look at the console? Didn't you see the objects logged? [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820). If that's not what you want, I'm afraid it's not clear what you want (but it *does* "work").

Comment: found answer i took data in var jsondata and following code works perfect  == 
    parseddata =jQuery.parseJSON(jsondata)
        $.each(parseddata , function  (index,entry) {
        
          $("#out").append(index + "<BR>")

          $.each (entry , function(ind,ent){ $("#out").append(ent.Type+   + "<BR>") })
        
        })

Comment: @FelixKling i found answer  http://jsfiddle.net/KL7r2/

Comment: @PatrickHofman no regret,they dont give answer so i found my answer myself :)

Comment: Yep, that's exactly the same as what I wrote, just using jQuery's `$.each` method instead of `for` loops.

Comment: @FelixKling but using that for loop it wont give what i exactly need , i had also tried that way too , but wont get expected results

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON has 2 top-level elements. So, you can't logically iterate across the entire document (without flattening it).

But you can iteration across the "MATHS" and "LOGICAL REASONING" elements.

For example, using underscore:

```
_(data.MATHS).each(function(item) {
  var section = item.SECTION;
  var type = item.TYPE;
  var count = item.COUNT;

  // Now do something with them
});
```

Note the different access method to the 'LOGICAL REASONING' element, because of the space.

```
_(data['LOGICAL REASONING').each(function(item) {
  var section = item.SECTION;
  var type = item.TYPE;
  var count = item.COUNT;

  // Now do something with them
});
```

If you wanted all the data together, one way of doing it would be:

```
var flattened = _.union(data.MATHS, data['LOGICAL REASONING']);

_(flattened).each(function(item) {
  // Process...
});
```

Check out the underscore docs for some more information about the possibilities. Many ways to skin a cat.

http://underscorejs.org/

Cheers.