# Trouble accessing JSON child

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having trouble accessing child elements of a JSON file. Here is my JSON file:

```
var actualGameData = '[{
  "gameBackgroundMusic": "background.wav",
  "narratorCongratulations": "congratulations.wav",
  "hitSound": [
    "hit1.wav",
    "hit2.wav",
    "hit3.wav"
  ],
  "narratorHitSound": [
    "narratorhit1.wav",
    "narratorhit2.wav",
    "narratorhit3.wav"
  ],
  "narratorMissSound": [
    "narratormiss1.wav",
    "narratormiss2.wav",
    "narratormiss3.wav"
  ],
  "levels": {
    "Tumble in the Castle": {
      "Time Limit": 60000,
      "Background Image": {
        "Object Name": "backgroundCastle",
        "Image": "backgroundCastle.png"
      },
      "Foreground Image": {
        "Object Name": "foregroundCastle",
        "Image": "foregroundCastle.png"
      },
      "Targets": {
        "Target1": {
          "x axis": 45,
          "y axis": 11
        },
        "Target2": {
          "x axis": 545,
          "y axis": 141
        },
        "Target3": {
          "x axis": 495,
          "y axis": 33
        }
      }
    },
    "Jungle Rumble": {
      "Time Limit": 30000,
      "Background Image": {
        "Object Name": "backgroundJungle",
        "Image": "backgroundJungle.png"
      },
      "Foreground Image": {
        "Object Name": "foregroundJungle",
        "Image": "foregroundJungle.png"
      },
      "Targets": {
        "Target1": {
          "x axis": 465,
          "y axis": 141
        },
        "Target2": {
          "x axis": 525,
          "y axis": 111
        },
        "Target3": {
          "x axis": 405,
          "y axis": 63
        }
      }
    }
  }

}];
```

And I want to access all of the level names. What I want to see is 2 alerts showing: "Tumble in the castle" and "Jungle Rumble". I've tried the following, but it doesn't work. Any ideas? :) Many thanks.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="game.json"></script>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

  var obj = $.parseJSON(actualGameData);
      $.each(obj, function() {
          alert(this['levels.child']);
      });



});
        </script>



    <span></span>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: and [How do I enumerate the properties of a javascript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/85992/218196)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(actualGameData);
$.each(obj, function() {
     for (var levelName in this.levels) {
         alert(levelName);
     }
});
```

The for-loop here is actually iterating over the *keys* or properties of your `levels` object. If you want to access the data for that level, you can do this in that loop:

```
 for (var levelName in this.levels) {
     alert(levelName);
     var levelDetail = this.levels[levelName];
     var timeLimit = levelDetail['Time Limit'];
 }
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5dvqY/)

Comment: Fantastic that did it Cory thank you. I'll list it as the accepted answer when the time limit runs out. Has my JSON file been written in a structured way in your opinion?

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward: structurally it seems fine; though I would ditch spaces in the property names and stick with camelCasePropertyNames (`levelDetail['Time Limit']` vs. `levelDetail.timeLimit`, for instance).

Comment: I would not use `for (... in ...)`, though.

Comment: @andrew: You actually don't have a JSON file, you have a javascript file which declares one variable with a string value that happens to be JSON. In that case there is no reason to use JSON at all. Just directly create the array and object, e.g. `var actualGameData = [{gameBackgroundMusic: ..., ...}];` and remove `var obj = $.parseJSON(...);`.

Comment: @FelixKling: Definitely, I did that in my fiddle but forgot to mention it.

Comment: @FelixKling I need to keep it in that structure as JSON doesn't work locally (this is for a phone app). And I need to be able to add levels easily :)

Comment: @andrew: I'm not saying you should change the structure, I'm saying you should create the array directly, without using JSON. Basically just remove the single quotes that delimit the string. It will make it even easier to add new data. See, what you are doing is basically `var json = '[1,2,3]'; var arr = JSON.parse(json);`, which is much easier written as `var arr = [1,2,3];`.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the level names into an array quickly with `Object.keys` and then loop over them.

```
var levelNames = Object.keys(actualGameData[0].levels);

for (var i = 0, l = levelNames.length; i < l; i++) {
  alert(levelNames[i]);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/8LGWN/)