# JavaScript - check for existence of a prototype instance within an object

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I want to check an object to see if any instances of the `carDoor` prototype exist

```
function carDoor(side) {
    this.side = side;
}

var Car = {

    "door1": new carDoor("left"),
    "door2": new carDoor("right")

}
```

Does the Car object have a door? - **How can I check in a way that will work for any prototype?**

*Assume that you don't know or control the name of the property.*

Comment: Combine http://stackoverflow.com/q/85992/218196 with http://stackoverflow.com/q/332422/218196.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `instanceof` operator:

```
for (key in Car) {
   if (Car.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if (Car[key] instanceof carDoor) {
          // ...
      }
   }   
}
```

Comment: What advantages / disadvantages does this approach have versus `Car.door1.constructor === carDoor;`?

Comment: @jt0dd `instanceof` operator also checks the inherited constructors but the `constructor` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you could do:

`Car.door1.constructor === carDoor;`

That will return true.

Comment: And as far as naming convention goes, I would name them CarDoor and car.

Comment: Oh. Cool. I didn't know that constructed objects had that property.

Comment: Both answers (at the time of writing) that use the `constructor` property presuppose you know the name of the property; given that you're *naming the property* `door1` (`door2` etc.) checking for the existence of that property should surely be enough?

Comment: What if I'm developing a public library, and I need to check for a certain prototype instance where the user of the library can name the prototype instance whatever he/she wants? @DavidThomas

Comment: What if..? Well, that might have been useful information to add to your question, and left me feeling a little less bemused by your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your question.. or at least a half of it, verify the constructor of the `Car` object properties and it'll return true.

```
if (Car.door2.constructor === carDoor)
// ...
```

Comment: Oh, didn't see @ramdog gave this answer too.