# How can I find the string value of a property given it's value

Tags: javascript

I created something similar to an ENUM like this:

```
 var ContentStatusId = {
        All: 0,
        Production: 1,
        Review: 2,
        Draft: 3,
        Concept: 4
    }
```

so when I set:

```
var a = ContentStatusId.All
```

it gets the value of 0

How can I go in the other direction?  If I know a = 0 and a comes from ContentStatusId then how can I get the string "All"?

Comment: Iterate over the properties and compare the values. [How do I enumerate the properties of a javascript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the properties until you find the one with the value you want

```
function findVal(obj, val) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { // skip inherited properties
            if (obj[prop] == val) {
                return prop;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to iterate through the properties and check whether they equal the value on each iteration:

```
for (var property in ContentStatusId) {
    if (ContentStatusId.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        if (ContentStatusId[property] == /*value to look for*/) {
            console.log(property);
        }
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/hD6eG/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly. You'd have to store the key somewhere...

```
var a = ['All', ContentStatusId.All];
```

or, more advanced:

```
var a = {
    source: ContentStatusId,
    key: 'All',
    update: function () {
        this.value = this.source[this.key];
    }
};
a.update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you have to do, you can either iterate over the object or if you have to do this more often, just create an array where you can do your reverse-lookup:

```
var ContentStatusIdReverse = ["All","Production",...]

ContentStatusIdReverse[0] // Yields "All"
```

You can create this array in the first place by iterating over your object once, and all consecutive lookups can be done via the array.