# Count of objects in array Jquery?

Tags: jquery, loops

I have this array obejcts

```
  var customers =
[{"id":"1", "name":"John","position":"CEO","office":"NY", "active": "1"},
{"id":"2", "name":"Michael","position":"CEO","office":"NY", "active": "1"},
{"id":"3", "name":"Wanda","position":"CEO","office":"NY", "active": "0"},
{"id":"3", "name":"Novak","position":"CEO","office":"NY", "active": "0"}];
```

What i need is to get number of customers in that array,

```
 var indexID = 4;
```

And also a new array that will look like this

```
var newArray =
    [{"id", "name","position","office"}];
```

This new array will only collect title just once and with out active

Comment: first code is invalid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all json is not valid. it should be:

```
var customers =
[{"id":"1", "name":"John","position":"CEO","office":"NY", "active": "1"},
{"id":"2", "name":"Michael","position":"CEO","office":"NY", "active": "1"},
{"id":"3", "name":"Wanda","position":"CEO","office":"NY", "active": "0"},
{"id":"3", "name":"Novak","position":"CEO","office":"NY", "active": "0"}];
```

you can get count using `length` this way:

```
var count = customers.length;
```

and you can create new array with desired properties only using `map()`:

```
var newArray = customers.map(function(item,index){

    return { "id": item.id, "name": item.name,"position": item.position }

});
```

### WORKING EXAMPLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/abu209tb/

Comment: First part is ok, the problem is in the second, because it is hardcoded, what if the customers array changed, i need something to get only title

Comment: which title you want to get?

Comment: I need all elements in new array but only last no

Comment: what you mean by last no?

Comment: you can filter them @Gorostas

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure .length is what you are looking for..

```
var indexID = customers.length;
var newArray = Object.keys(customers[0]);
```

thanks goes to this link for reference material: 
[How do I enumerate the properties of a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)

Comment: you have enough reputation to leave this answer as a comment.

Comment: what am i missing here? I'm answering the question? /me confused

Comment: you edited the answer your intial answer was only a single line to use `.length` ... now its fine...

Comment: ah ok, my very first stab at an answer was too simple for an "answer"... was just a placeholder while i gather my thoughts