# get data through JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have some JSON below, What I would like to do is iterate through the JSON file and pull out the 'title' element and make a list. Could anybody help?

```
{ "slides" : {
        "sl_0_0" : {
            "title" : "Slide 0-0",
            "copy" : "Copy for slide 0-0",
            "link" : "sl_0_0.html"
        },
        "sl_1_0" : {
            "title" : "Slide 1-0",
            "copy" : "Copy for slide 1-0",
            "link" : "sl_1_0.html"
        },
        "sl_1_1" : {
            "title" : "Slide 1-1",
            "copy" : "Copy for slide 1-1",
            "link" : "sl_1_1.html"
        },
        "sl_2_0" : {
            "title" : "Slide 2_0",
            "copy" : "Copy for slide 2_0",
            "link" : "sl_2_0.html"
        },
        "sl_2_1" : {
            "title" : "Slide 2_1",
            "copy" : "Copy for slide 2_1",
            "link" : "sl_2_1.html"
        },
        "sl_2_2" : {
            "title" : "Slide 2_2",
            "copy" : "Copy for slide 2_2",
            "link" : "sl_2_2.html"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: soooooo... you want us to write your code? what have you tried so far? what language are you using?... we don't have a lot to go on here...

Comment: Which programming language are you using ?

Comment: No, I wasn't expecting you to write my code. I haven't used JSON before so was just looking for some leaders:

Comment: Here's what I have so far:
var info = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
  var output = '';
  for (var i = 0; i <= Object.keys(info.slides).length-1; i++) {
   // for (key in info.slides[i]) {
   //  if (info.slides[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
   //   output += '<li>' +
   //   '<a href="' + info.slides[i][key] +
   //   '">' + key + '</a>';
   //   '</li>';
   //  }
   // };


  alert(Object.keys(info.slides)[i].title);

   // output += '<li>' +
   // '<a href="' + info.slides[i].title +
   // '">' + key + '</a>';
   // '</li>';



  };

Comment: Add the code into your question. It's not readable as a comment.

Comment: And what's the problem with the code you have?

Comment: Its not returning the desired data. I can loop through 'slides' using Object.keys(info.slides), but this returns a string, returning 'sl_0_0', 'sl_1_1' etc. For each of these I then need to dive down for the title. So info.slides[0].title returns an undefined.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/85992/218196 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196.

Comment: Worked it out, thanks people:
for (var i = 0; i <= Object.keys(info.slides).length-1; i++) {    
   var str = Object.keys(info.slides)[i];
   output += '<li>' + '<a href = "' + info.slides[str].link + '">' + info.slides[str].title + '</a>' + '</li>'; 
  };

Comment: for (var i = 0; i <= Object.keys(info.slides).length-1; i++) {    
   var str = Object.keys(info.slides)[i];
   output += '<li>' + '<a href = "' + info.slides[str].link + '">' + info.slides[str].title + '</a>' + '</li>'; 
  };

Comment: Sorry, just trying to display code in a useful format!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because shows no effort

Answer (score 0):

You treat a JSON object just as you would any other javascript object.  So, you can interate through it using a for loops like this:

```
var jsonObj = { /* your JSON object here */ };
for ( var id in jsonObj.slides ) {
    var slide = jsonObj.slides[id];
    var title = slide.title; //etc.
    /* Now you can build your list */
}
```