# how to change <a> tag with the function of edit and delete a record of a table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr class="rows">      
        <td>@item.CourseName</td>
        <td>@item.ClassName</td>
        <td>@item.StuName</td>
        <td>@item.Age</td> 
        <td>@item.Scores</td>
        <td>             
            @Html.ActionLink("edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID })
            <a id="@item.ID" href="javascript:" onclick="deletescore(@item.ID)">delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

here is the jquery code i tried to write.  i don't know how to write the last `<td>` of each `<tr>`

```js
function deletescore(id) {
  alert(id)
  return false;
  jQuery.ajax({
    data:{"id":id},
    type: "POST",
    url: "/View/Delete",
    success: function (data) {
      alert(data)
      jQuery("#tablelist").attr("tr").remove(this);
    },
    error: function () {
      alert("未删除");
    }
  });
}

 function makeTable(container, data) {
   var table = $("<table></table>").addClass('TableMaker');
   function thmaker () {
     //添加表头
     var row = $("<tr></tr>");
     var thdata = ["学科", "班级", "姓名", "年龄", "分数", "用户操作"]
     table.append(row);
     //row.append($("<th/>").text（thdata）)
     for(var item in thdata) {
       $("<td></td>").text(thdata[item]).appendTo(row);
     }
   }
   thmaker();
   $.each(data, function (rowIndex, r) {
     var rowToAdd = "";  
     var $newLink = $('<a href="#" id=newLink>编辑</a>');
     var $newLinkTarget = '@Url.Action("Edit", "View")?id=' +r.ID;
     $newLink.attr("href", $newLinkTarget);
     rowToAdd += "<tr>"
     rowToAdd += "<td>" + r.CourseName + "</td>";
     rowToAdd += "<td>" + r.ClassName + "</td>";
     rowToAdd += "<td>" + r.StuName + "</td>";
     rowToAdd += "<td>" + r.Age + "</td>";
     rowToAdd += "<td>" + r.Scores + "</td>";
     rowToAdd += "<td>" + $newLinkTarget + "</td>";     
     rowToAdd += "<td><a href='javascript:' did='r.ID' onclick='deletescore(did)'>删除</a></td>";
     rowToAdd += "</tr>";
     table.append(rowToAdd);
  });
 container.append(table);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  makeTable($(".tablemaker"), infos.info);
});
```

Comment: What is the actual issue? Are you trying to post the `item.ID` value of the row to a method which deletes the item, and then if successful, remove that row from the table? What does the `makeTable` function have to do with it?

Comment: oh i built the table with jquery. so there will be no html code about the table .

Comment: Sorry, still don't get it. What then is the `@foreach (var item in Model)` code that builds a table?

Comment: And what is `<a href='javascript:' did='r.ID' onclick='deletescore(did)'>` supposed to do?

Comment: yes @foreach can build the table . and function well . but now i need to build the table with the same function(delete and edit) using jquery.as the js code, the code i have write can show the record of table. but i don't know how to add the function of edit and delete.

Comment: I just added an answer for building the link with the razor code (you should not have included that in your question). I'll update it shortly for the table script.

Comment: the <a href='javascript:' did='r.ID' onclick='deletescore(did)'> is i try to add the <a> tag url and when click on the <a> it will delete the row.  The r.ID is the key to find the row. I have write the function of deletescore on the js code which function as the bring the id as parameter and send the action and delete the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to render a link in each row that posts the associated items ID value, then in the razor code

```
<a class="deleterow" data-id=@item.ID href="#">delete</a>
```

Script

```
$('.deleterow').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).data(id); // get the rows item id value
  $.post('@Url.Action("Delete", "View")', { ID: id }, function(data) {
    if (data) {
      $(this).closest('tr').remove(); // remove the row
    } else {
      // oops
    }
  }
});
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Delete(int ID)
{
  // Delete the item based on its ID.
  return Json(true); // if successful, otherwise return null; 
}
```

As a side note, your script to generate a new table is rendering invalid html, for example

```
$.each(data, function (rowIndex, r) {
  var $newLink = $('<a href="#" id=newLink>编辑</a>');
```

is creating multiple links with the `id="newLink"` attribute. You should class names instead.

**Edit**

For creating the table using jquery instead or the razor code, adjust the script to

```
var editUrl = '@Url.Action("Edit", "View")';

...
$.each(data, function (rowIndex, r) {
  var row = $('<tr></tr>');
  row.append($('<td></td>').text(r.CourseName);
  row.append($('<td></td>').text(r.ClassName);
  row.append($('<td></td>').text(r.StuName);
  row.append($('<td></td>').text(r.Age);
  row.append($('<td></td>').text(r.Scores);
  row.append($('<a></a>').attr('href', url + '/' + r.id).text('edit')); // include .addClass('???') if you need it
  row.append($('<a></a>').data('id', r.id).attr('href', '#').addClass('deleterow').text('delete'));
  table.append(row);
});
....
```

Comment: thanks so much. could you write the code down. i'm new in jquery.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment _could you write the code down_? What additional code do you require? and whats _i'm here in jquery_?

Comment: and the code <a class="deleterow" data-id=@item.ID href="#">delete</a> you have write. how could i write it using jquery!!!(      rowToAdd += "<td><a href='javascript:' did='r.ID' onclick='deletescore(did)'>删除</a></td>"; ) is the code i was try to do with it . could you write it down for me

Comment: Its in my edit (second last line)! `row.append($('<a></a>').data('id', r.id).attr('href', '#').addClass('deleterow').text('delete'));`

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use [this](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) to change an `<a>` tag.

Also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object) can help you with iterating through your object and building your table using [this](http://api.jquery.com/append/).