# JavaScript: Is it possible to iterate your OWN variables?

Tags: javascript, properties, closures, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to implement the "iterate" function (below) that iterates it's own variables that's not using deprecated JavaScript functionality?

```
(function () {
    var a = 1;
    var b = 2;
    var iterate = function () {
        var k;
        for (k in this) {     //WRONG IMPLEMENTATION!
            alert(this[k]);
            // a
            // b
            // iterate
        }
    };
}).call(this);
```

I set a breakpoint inside "iterate" and poked around in the debugger and was not able to figure out how to access the other variable names.  Also, after perhaps dozens of Google searches I've not been able to find an answer as the search hits usually refer to an *external* not *internal* perspective.

UPDATE: I got properties and variables confused.  Before editing, the original question was asking about iterating the properties.  I now realize those are variables.

Comment: I wouldn't call those "properties". They are local variables.

Comment: You will need to [distinguish between variables and properties](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572). Properties are iterable with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`, variables are not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enumerate the properties of a javascript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)

Comment: @Pinal, not a duplicate of that.

Comment: I updated the question title.

Comment: @PeteAlvin Perhaps you could update the question to clarify that you want to iterate over all in-scope variables (and not those belonging to an object)?  It seems several of us had the same misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Besides horrendous `eval` hacks you cannot access variables in any scope but the global scope (`window`) or an object's scope (`this`) in a dynamic way.

But you don't need to! If you want dynamic access to those variables, store them in an object:

```
var data = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
};
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I realized I could create a local object, perhaps with a short name like "o" and access like o.a and o.b.    I was hoping to eliminate the o.<variable> scoping syntax.  Looks like I'm out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).  Every object has this method whereby you can pass it a property name (i.e., what you get from iterating with a `for` loop) and learn whether that property is set on the given object (and therefore isn't inherited).  So, for example:

```
for (var k in this) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        // do something here...
    }
}
```

You might also want to look into [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) which has a *ton* of useful shortcuts for this and many similar tasks.

### Update

I think I may have misunderstood the question...  if you wanted to know whether there's a way to iterate over all in-scope variables, then: no, there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var j = (function (obj) {

        var a = 1;
        var b = 2;

        var iterate = function () {
            var k;
            for (k in this) {     
                console.log(k, this[k]);
            };
        }.bind(obj);
         obj["a"] = a; obj["b"] = b; obj["iterate"] = iterate;

       return obj
    }(Object.create(null))) || obj;
```

```js
var j = (function (obj) {
        
        var a = 1;
        var b = 2;
        
        var iterate = function () {
            var k;
            for (k in this) {     
                console.log(k, this[k]);
            };
        }.bind(obj);
         obj["a"] = a; obj["b"] = b; obj["iterate"] = iterate;
        
       return obj
    }(Object.create(null))) || obj;
    
    j.iterate();
    j.a = 5;
    j.iterate();
    console.log(j)
```

Comment: It looks like it's theoretically possible, but not "convenient."  The goal was to iterate without explicit programming the variable names.  But thank you for providing a solution!