# How to loop data in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object like these

```
var itemlist= {"50271":2,"50025":1,"90012":3}1
```

It indicates the reagent to include in a mixture. The property name is the ID of the reagent and the property value the quantity. I would like to generate HTML to display the reagents of a mixture as follows

```
<img src='50271.jpg'> x 2
<img src='50025.jpg'> x 1
<img src='90012.jpg'> x 3
```

How can I loop the object to get my expected output?

Comment: What you have is an **object**, represented as **object literal**. It is neither an array nor JSON. JSON is *language-independent, textual data-exchange format*, much like XML, YAML or CSV.

Comment: See [How do I enumerate the properties of a javascript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/85992/218196)

Comment: Also, there is no guarantee what order the properties will be iterated over. If you need a specific order, us an array.

Comment: sorry I receive it from php json_encode() function

Comment: @user3789191: Doesn't matter where the data came from or in which format.

Comment: Reopened the dup marking because this question also asks how to generate the desired HTML from the data structure which was not covered in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the properties of an object using the `for (prop in obj)` syntax and generate your specific HTML like this:

```
var itemlist = {"50271":2,"50025":1,"90012":3};
var html = "";
for (var prop in itemList) {
    html += "<img src='" + prop + ".jpg'> x " + itemList[prop];
}
// insert the html somewhere now
```

P.S. I would guess you may want a `<br>` after each line.

P.P.S. Data in a javascript object has no guaranteed order so the iteration could end up in any order.  You have to use an array if you want a collection in a particular order or you can collect all the keys of the object first and then sort the keys before using them.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to loop through the object like this

```
for (var key in itemlist) {
  if (itemlist.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    alert(key + " -> " + itemlist[key]);
  }
}
```

As shown here:
[How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object)