# Get properties of class in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've the following class:

```
export class Test {

        private _rowsCount: string;
        public get RowsCount(): string {
            return this._rowsCount;
        };
        public set RowsCount(value: string) {
            this._rowsCount = value;
        };

        private _rowsCount2: string;
        public get RowsCount2(): string {
            return this._rowsCount2;
        };
        public set RowsCount2(value: string) {
            this._rowsCount2 = value;
        };
    }
```

I need to iterate over the properties in a specific class, I tried the following:

```
Object.keys(this).forEach((key)=> {
    console.log(key);
});
```

But the problem that this iterate just over the `private` fields, I tried also the following I got all the `methods` and `properties`:

```
    for (var property in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            console.log(property);                
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: The `for/in` loop gave you all of them, that's not what you're after? What are you trying to get?

Comment: The for/in gave also the methods and the constructor if exist!, and I don't want those, I need just the public properties!

Comment: By "properties" you mean getters/setters only? Or members as well? You need to be more precise about what you're asking as it isn't clear at all.

Comment: I need to get only the getters/setters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get functions (methods) of a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054910/get-functions-methods-of-a-class)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get properties of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636292/get-properties-of-a-class)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you need to only get the getters/setters, then you'll need to do something like:

```
class Test {
    ...

    public static getGetters(): string[] {
        return Object.keys(this.prototype).filter(name => {
            return typeof Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this.prototype, name)["get"] === "function"
        });
    }

    public static getSetters(): string[] {
        return Object.keys(this.prototype).filter(name => {
            return typeof Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this.prototype, name)["set"] === "function"
        });
    }
}

Test.getGetters(); // ["RowsCount", "RowsCount2"]
Test.getSetters(); // ["RowsCount", "RowsCount2"]
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Test%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_rowsCount%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%20RowsCount()%3A%20string%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._rowsCount%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20set%20RowsCount(value%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._rowsCount%20%3D%20value%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_rowsCount2%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%20RowsCount2()%3A%20string%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._rowsCount2%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20set%20RowsCount2(value%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._rowsCount2%20%3D%20value%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20getGetters()%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Object.keys(this.prototype).filter(name%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20typeof%20Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this.prototype%2C%20name)%5B%22get%22%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22function%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20getSetters()%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Object.keys(this.prototype).filter(name%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20typeof%20Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this.prototype%2C%20name)%5B%22set%22%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22function%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0ATest.getGetters()%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22RowsCount%22%2C%20%22RowsCount2%22%5D%0ATest.getSetters()%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22RowsCount%22%2C%20%22RowsCount2%22%5D))

---

You can put the static methods in a base class, and then when you extend it the subclass will have those static methods as well:

```
class Base {
    public static getGetters(): string[] {
        return Object.keys(this.prototype).filter(name => {
            return typeof Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this.prototype, name)["get"] === "function"
        });
    }

    public static getSetters(): string[] {
        return Object.keys(this.prototype).filter(name => {
            return typeof Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this.prototype, name)["set"] === "function"
        });
    }
}

class Test extends Base {
   ...
}

Test.getGetters(); // work the same
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Base%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20getGetters()%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Object.keys(this.prototype).filter(name%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20typeof%20Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this.prototype%2C%20name)%5B%22get%22%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22function%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20getSetters()%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Object.keys(this.prototype).filter(name%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20typeof%20Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this.prototype%2C%20name)%5B%22set%22%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22function%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Test%20extends%20Base%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_rowsCount%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%20RowsCount()%3A%20string%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._rowsCount%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20set%20RowsCount(value%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._rowsCount%20%3D%20value%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_rowsCount2%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%20RowsCount2()%3A%20string%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._rowsCount2%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20set%20RowsCount2(value%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._rowsCount2%20%3D%20value%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0ATest.getGetters()%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22RowsCount%22%2C%20%22RowsCount2%22%5D%0ATest.getSetters()%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22RowsCount%22%2C%20%22RowsCount2%22%5D))

If you want these methods to be instance methods then you can do this:

```
class Base {
    public getGetters(): string[] {
        return Object.keys(this.constructor.prototype).filter(name => {
            return typeof Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this.constructor.prototype, name)["get"] === "function"
        });
    }

    public getSetters(): string[] {
        return Object.keys(this.constructor.prototype).filter(name => {
            return typeof Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this.constructor.prototype, name)["set"] === "function"
        });
    }
}
```

The change is that instead of using `this.prototype` you're using `this.constructor.prototype`.
Then you simply:

```
let a = new Test();
a.getGetters(); // ["RowsCount", "RowsCount2"]
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Base%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getGetters()%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Object.keys(this.constructor.prototype).filter(name%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20typeof%20Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this.constructor.prototype%2C%20name)%5B%22get%22%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22function%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getSetters()%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Object.keys(this.constructor.prototype).filter(name%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20typeof%20Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this.constructor.prototype%2C%20name)%5B%22set%22%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22function%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Test%20extends%20Base%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_rowsCount%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%20RowsCount()%3A%20string%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._rowsCount%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20set%20RowsCount(value%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._rowsCount%20%3D%20value%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_rowsCount2%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%20RowsCount2()%3A%20string%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._rowsCount2%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20set%20RowsCount2(value%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._rowsCount2%20%3D%20value%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20Test()%3B%0Aa.getGetters()%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22RowsCount%22%2C%20%22RowsCount2%22%5D))

---

#### Edit

Based on a comment by @Twois, who pointed out that it won't work when targetting es6, here's a version that will work:

```
class Base {
    public static getGetters(): string[] {
        return Reflect.ownKeys(this.prototype).filter(name => {
            return typeof Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this.prototype, name)["get"] === "function";
        }) as string[];
    }

    public static getSetters(): string[] {
        return Reflect.ownKeys(this.prototype).filter(name => {
            return typeof Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this.prototype, name)["set"] === "function";
        }) as string[];
    }
}
```

The main difference: using `Reflect.ownKeys(this.prototype)` instead of `Object.keys(this.prototype)`.

Comment: Good!, is it any way to do a RootTest that have those methods and every nested class can invoke them to get his own getters/setters? I noticed that if I change definition of the method to be non-static will not found the prototype

Comment: This is not work anymore if  the target is es6 or newer, because of TS now use the native js getter and setter.

Comment: can we use `Keyof` ?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is for the class you want to use it extend the class above and make the properties public for this reason;

```
   class TestExposed extend Test {
      public _rowsCount: string;
      public _rowsCount2: string; 
   }
```

And in your Test class make the private protected:

```
class Test {
    protected _rowsCount: string;
    public get RowsCount(): string {
        return this._rowsCount;
    };
    public set RowsCount(value: string) {
        this._rowsCount = value;
    };

    protected _rowsCount2: string;
    public get RowsCount2(): string {
        return this._rowsCount2;
    };
    public set RowsCount2(value: string) {
        this._rowsCount2 = value;
    };
}
```

Then you should be able to iterate over the properties in an external class;

**But if you want to have the values; Why not make a function that exposes the values by returning them in an array or log them as a string;**